# Internal`Bag inside Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, tensors, undocumented

Since `` Internal`Bag ``, `` Internal`StuffBag `` and `` Internal`BagPart `` can be compiled down, it is a precious source for various applications. There were already many questions why `AppendTo` is so slow, and which ways exist to make a dynamically grow-able array which is faster. Since inside `Compile` many tricks can simply not be used, which is for instance the case for `Sow` and `Reap`, this is a good alternative.

**A fast, compiled version of `AppendTo`:** For a comparison I will use `AppendTo` directly for an easy loop. Ignore the fact that this would not be necessary here, since we know the number of elements in the result list. In a real application, you maybe wouldn't know this.

```
appendTo = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}},
  Module[{i, list = Most[{0}]},
    For[i = 1, i <= n, ++i,
      AppendTo[list, i];
    ];
    list
  ]
]
```

Using `` Internal`Bag `` is not as expensive, since in the above code, the list is copied in each iteration. This is not the case for `` Internal`Bag ``.

```
stuffBag = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}},
  Module[{i, list = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]]},
    For[i = 1, i <= n, ++i,
      Internal`StuffBag[list, i];
    ];
    Internal`BagPart[list, All]
  ]
]
```

Comparing the run time of both functions uncovers the potential of `` Internal`Bag ``:

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[#[10^5]]] & /@ {appendTo, stuffBag}

(*
    {4.298237, 0.003207}
*)
```

### Usage and features

The following information was collected from different sources. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762) is an article from Daniel Lichtblau who was kind enough to give some insider information. A question on MathGroup led to a conversation with [Oleksandr Rasputinov](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Jan/msg00722.html) who knew about the third argument of `` Internal`BagPart ``. Various other posts on StackOverflow [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmathematica%5D+%2BStuffBag) which I will not mention explicitly. I will restrict the following to the usage of `` Internal`Bag `` and `Compile` *together*. While we have 4 functions (`` Internal`Bag ``, `` Internal`StuffBag ``, `` Internal`BagPart ``, `` Internal`BagLength ``), only the first three can be compiled. Therefore, one has to explicitly count the elements which are inserted into the bag if needed (or use `Length` on `All` elements).

- `` Internal`Bag[] `` creates an empty bag of type real. When an `Integer` is inserted it is converted to `Real`. `True` is converted to `1.0` and `False` to `0.0`. Other types of bags are possible too. See below.
- `` Internal`StuffBag[b, elm] `` adds an element `elm` to the bag `b`. It is possible to create a bag of bags inside compile. This way it is easy to create a tensor of arbitrary rank.
- `` Internal`BagPart[b,i] `` gives the `i`-th part of the bag `b`. `` Internal`BagPart[b,All] `` returns a list of all. The `Span` operator `;;` can be used too. `` Internal`BagPart `` can have a third argument which is the used `Head` for the returned expression.
- Variables of `` Internal`Bag `` (or general inside `Compile`) require a hint to the compile for deducing the type. A bag of integers can be declared as `` list = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]] ``
- To my knowledge supported number-types contain `Integer`, `Real` and `Complex`.

### Examples

The important property of the following examples is that they are completely compiled. There is no call to the kernel, and using the `` Internal`Bag `` in such a way should most likely speed things up.

The famous sum of Gauss; adding the numbers from 1 to 100. Note that the numbers are not explicitly added. I use the third argument to replace the `List` head with `Plus`. The only possible heads inside `Compile` are `Plus` and `Times` and `List`.

```
sumToN = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}},
  Module[{i, list = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]]},
    For[i = 1, i <= n, ++i,
      Internal`StuffBag[list, i];
    ];
    Internal`BagPart[list, All, Plus]
    ]
  ];
sumToN[100]
```

Creating a rank-2 tensor by creating the inner bag directly inside the constructor of the outer one:

```
tensor2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}, {m, _Integer, 0}},
  Module[{list = Internal`Bag[Most[{1}]], i, j},
    Table[
      Internal`StuffBag[
        list, 
        Internal`Bag[Table[j, {j, m}]]
      ],
    {i, n}];
   Table[Internal`BagPart[Internal`BagPart[list, i], All], {i, n}]
  ]
]
```

An equivalent function which inserts every number separately

```
tensor2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}, {m, _Integer, 0}},
  Module[{
    list = Internal`Bag[Most[{1}]], 
    elm = Internal`Bag[Most[{1}]], i, j
  },
  Table[
    elm = Internal`Bag[Most[{1}]];
    Table[Internal`StuffBag[elm, j], {j, m}];
    Internal`StuffBag[list, elm], 
  {i, n}];
  Table[Internal`BagPart[Internal`BagPart[list, i], All], {i, n}]
 ]
]
```

A `Position` for integer matrices:

```
position = Compile[{{mat, _Integer, 2}, {elm, _Integer, 0}},
  Module[{result = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]], i, j},
    Table[
      If[mat[[i, j]] === elm,
        Internal`StuffBag[result, Internal`Bag[{i, j}]]
      ],
    {i, Length[mat]}, {j, Length[First[mat]]}];
    Table[
      Internal`BagPart[pos, {1, 2}],
    {pos, Internal`BagPart[result, All]}] 
  ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"      
]
```

This last example can easily be used to measure some timings against the kernel function:

```
times = Table[
  Block[{data = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {n, n}]},
    Transpose[{
      {n, n}, 
      Sqrt[First[AbsoluteTiming[#[data, 1]]] & /@ {position, Position}]
    }]
  ], {n, 100, 1000, 200}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[times]]
```

[image: plot of run times]

### Open Questions

- Are there simpler/other ways to tell the compiler the type of a local variable? What bothers me here is that this is not really explained in the docs. It is only mentioned shortly how to *define* (not *declare*) a tensor. When a user wants to have an empty tensor, it is completely unintuitive that he has to use a trick like `Most[{1}]`. Declaring variables would be one of the first things I need, when I would be new to `Compile`. In [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compile/tutorial/Operation.html), I didn't find any hint to this.
- Are there further features of `Bag` which may be important to know in combination with `Compile`?
- The timing function of `position` above leaks memory. After the run `{n, 100, 3000, 200}` there is 20GB of memory occupied. I haven't investigated this issue really deeply, but when I don't return the list of positions, the memory seems OK. Actually, the memory for the returned positions should be collected after the `Block` finishes. My system here is Ubuntu 10.04 and *Mathematica* 8.0.4.

Comment: Hi, halirutan. I am confused about the performance of Bag vs Append. I define `appendc = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}, {y, _Integer}}, Append[x, y]]` and ``bagc = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}, {y, _Integer}},
  Module[{bag},
   bag = Internal`Bag[x];
   Internal`StuffBag[bag, y];
   Internal`BagPart[bag, All]]]`` . Timing `RepeatedTiming[Function[{x}, #[Range[100], x]] /@ Range[10000]][[
   1]] & /@ {appendc, bagc}` shows {0.041, 0.079}, so my bagc is slower than appendc, what is wrong? I suppose bagc should be faster

Comment: Well, there is no use in using `Bag` or `Append` to append *one* number to a list! If you have a loop that calculates results one after another and you append every new result to the list of existing results, **this** is that situation where `Append` is bad and `Bag` kicks in with all its performance advantages.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Create a bag is time consuming. If I define ``bagc = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}, {y, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{bag}, bag = Internal`Bag[x]]]`` without any stuffbag manipulation, it is already slower then append version

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I am somewhat reluctant to offer this as an answer since it is inherently difficult to comprehensively address questions on undocumented functionality. Nonetheless, the following observations do constitute partial answers to points raised in the question and are likely to be of value to anyone trying to write practical compiled code using `Bag`s. However, caution is always highly advisable when using undocumented functions in a new way, and this is no less true for `Bag`s.

#### The type of `Bag`s

1. As far as the *Mathematica* virtual machine is concerned, `Bag`s are a numeric type, occupying a scalar `Integer`, `Real`, or `Complex` register, and can contain only scalars or other `Bag`s. They can be created empty, using the trick described in the question, or pre-stuffed:

   - with a scalar, using `` Internal`Bag[val] `` (where *val* is a scalar of the desired type)
   - with several scalars, using `` Internal`Bag[tens, lvl] ``, where *tens* is a full-rank tensor of the desired numeric type and *lvl* is a level specification analogous to the second argument of `Flatten`. For compiled code, *lvl* $\ge$ `ArrayDepth[tens]`, as `Bag`s cannot directly contain tensors.
2. `` Internal`StuffBag `` can only be used to insert values of the same type as the register the `Bag` occupies, a type castable to that type without loss of information (e.g. `Integer` to `Real`, or `Real` to `Complex`), or another `Bag`. Tensors can be inserted after being flattened appropriately using the third argument of `StuffBag`, which behaves in the same way as the second argument of `Bag` as described above. Attempts to stuff other items (e.g. un-flattened tensors or values of non-castable types) into a `Bag` will compile into `MainEvaluate` calls; however, sharing `Bag`s between the *Mathematica* interpreter and virtual machine has not been fully implemented as of *Mathematica* 8, so these calls will not work as expected. As this is relatively easy to do by mistake and there will not necessarily be any indication that it has happened, it is important to check that the compiled bytecode is free of such calls.

Example:

```
cf = Compile[{},
 Module[{b = Internal`Bag[{1, 2, 3}, 1]},
  Internal`StuffBag[b, {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, 2];
  Internal`BagPart[b, All]
 ]
]
```

`cf[]` gives:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

#### Nested `Bag`s

These are created simply by stuffing one `Bag` into another, and do not have any special type associated with them except the types of the registers containing the pieces. In particular, there is no "nested `Bag` type". Per the casting rules given above, it is theoretically possible to stuff `Integer` `Bag`s into a `Real` `Bag` and later extract them into `Integer` registers (for example). However, this technique is not to be recommended as the result depends on the virtual machine version; for instance, the following code is compiled into identical bytecode in versions 5.2, 7, and 8, but gives different results:

```
cf2 = Compile[{},
 Module[{
    br = Internal`Bag@Most[{0.}],
    parts = Most[{0.}],
    bi = Internal`Bag@Most[{0}]
   },
  Internal`StuffBag[bi, Range[10], 1];
  Internal`StuffBag[br, bi];
  parts = Internal`BagPart[br, All];
  Internal`BagPart[First[parts], All]
 ]
]
```

The result from versions 5.2 and 7:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

The result from version 8:

```
{1.}
```

Stuffing `Bag`s of mixed `Real` and `Integer` types into a `Real` `Bag` produces even less useful results, since pointer casts are performed by `` Internal`BagPart `` without regard to the original type of each constituent `Bag`, resulting in corrupted numerical values. However, nesting bags works correctly in all versions provided that the inner and outer bags are of identical types. It is also possible to stuff a bag into itself to create a circular reference, although the practical value of this is probably quite limited.

#### Miscellaneous

1. Calling `` Internal`BagPart `` with a part specification other than `All` will crash *Mathematica* kernels prior to version 8.
2. `` Internal`Bag `` accepts a third argument, which should be a positive machine integer. The purpose of this argument is not clear, but in any case it cannot be used in compiled code.

Comment: So `Internal'Bag` is MMA's version of a smart array?  It strikes me as odd that `List` needs to be copied just to append an element (also, how do you create in-line code with a back-tick?)

Comment: @VF1 I am not exactly sure what a smart array is, but ``Internal`Bag`` is a (singly) linked list. `List` is in general a hybrid between a linked list and an array, but in the VM it is implemented as just a standard array. In top-level *Mathematica* you can build linked lists using `List`s, and this does not incur any copies, but by appending you run into issues due to the immutability of expressions, so that the copies are necessary.

Comment: That's what I meant by a smart array - linked list (or arraylist)

Comment: @OleksandrR. it seems that in M11, stuffbag an integer bag into a real bag will cause kernel crash. For example ``Compile[{}, Module[{bag, n}, bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0.}]];
   n = 5;
   Do[Internal`StuffBag[bag, 
     Internal`Bag[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 3]]], {i, 1, n}];
   Table[Internal`BagPart[Internal`BagPart[bag, i], All], {i, 1, 
     n}]]][]``

Comment: @matheorem thanks. Yes, I'm not too surprised that this causes big problems. Already in 8 we had a result that suggested memory was being corrupted somewhere.

Answer (score 21):

About your question regarding the definition of the type of local variables in Compile, Compile has an optional third argument that allows you do this in the same manner you specify arguments. It helps the compiler solve some type ambiguity issues sometimes as by default a local variable is considered a Real number.

This can be the case if a local variable is the result of another external function and the compiler cannot infer properly the type of the result of this external function. For example

```
f = Compile[{x, y}, {x, y}]
ff = Compile[{x,y}, x]

g =
  Compile[x,
     Module[{y},
        y = h[3., 4.];
        y[[1]] = 2+x;
        y
    ]
    ,
    {{h[__], _Real, 1}}
 ]

h = f;
g[1.] (*works*)

h = ff;
g[1.] (*error*)
```

Without {{h[__], _Real, 1}} the compilation of g would produce an error.

Comment: +1 Although I new this, I never got this running with the declaration of local variables. I didn't know that you have to put `y={}` together with the type specification. How would I use this to define a Bag of integers, or a Bag of Bags of integers? I would have to know the true internal structure of the pattern or not?

Comment: The y={} is just for this example, you don't need to always initialize your local variable when you declare it if you specify the type. I would be surprised that you could have a type related to bags, the only official ones are Integer, Real, Complex, and True | False. In such Mathematica experiments I don't know anything better then try and fail ... but never fail to try !

Comment: But the simple example `Compile[{}, Module[{y}, y], {{y, _Real, 1}}]` fails. Indeed, it seems this type specification at the end is completely ignored and your example only works because of the `y={}` and because you chose type `Real`. Try this `Compile[{}, Module[{y = {}}, AppendTo[y, 1]], {{y, _Integer, 1}}]` and you see, that the type is `{Real}` although I specified Integer and appended an integer.

Comment: Faysal, do you know any examples where adding a third argument to `Compile` has any effect? Would you consider updating your answer? I feel there should probably be a separate Q&A about this, but I was curious if you knew more.

Comment: For the record, I strongly feel that this answer is wrong and misleading in this context, i.e. I fully agree with @halirutan's reasoning. I don't really want to downvote you, because you're right that this is what the documentation claims. But I don't want people to be misled either.

Comment: I'll find a better example and will update the answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer, feel free to add any other example you may find relevant for the use of this third argument in Compile.

Comment: Faysal, thank you for the update. I probably should have notified you that I asked a [new question about this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43128/4330), maybe you saw it already.