# List of compilable functions

Tags: functions, compile

Is there somewhere a list on the functions that `Compile` can compile, or the cases in which a particular function can be compiled that I haven't found? 
I'd be glad even with a list of some of them which surprisingly aren't compilable, and how to do without them.

I am not happy every time I have to rewrite or redesign code because it seems to make external calls for functions I didn't expect. I'd like to know how you handle all that, what you keep in mind.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Yes, but this only exists in version 8 onwards and is undocumented:

```
Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort
```

giving, for reference:

```
{Abs, AddTo, And, Append, AppendTo, Apply, ArcCos, ArcCosh, ArcCot, ArcCoth, ArcCsc,
 ArcCsch, ArcSec, ArcSech, ArcSin, ArcSinh, ArcTan, ArcTanh, Arg, Array, ArrayDepth,
 Internal`Bag, Internal`BagPart, BitAnd, BitNot, BitOr, BitXor, Block, BlockRandom, Boole,
 Break, Cases, Catch, Ceiling, Chop, Internal`CompileError, System`Private`CompileSymbol,
 Complement, ComposeList, CompoundExpression, Conjugate, ConjugateTranspose, Continue,
 Cos, Cosh, Cot, Coth, Count, Csc, Csch, Decrement, Delete, DeleteCases, Dimensions,
 Divide, DivideBy, Do, Dot, Drop, Equal, Erf, Erfc, EvenQ, Exp, Fibonacci, First,
 FixedPoint, FixedPointList, Flatten, NDSolve`FEM`FlattenAll, Floor, Fold, FoldList, For,
 FractionalPart, FreeQ, Compile`GetElement, Goto, Greater, GreaterEqual, Gudermannian,
 Haversine, If, Im, Implies, Increment, Inequality, Compile`InnerDo, Insert,
 IntegerDigits, IntegerPart, Intersection, InverseGudermannian, InverseHaversine,
 Compile`IteratorCount, Join, Label, Last, Length, Less, LessEqual, List, Log, Log10,
 Log2, LucasL, Map, MapAll, MapAt, MapIndexed, MapThread, NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot,
 MatrixQ, Max, MemberQ, Min, Minus, Mod, Compile`Mod1, Module, Most, N, Negative, Nest,
 NestList, NonNegative, Not, OddQ, Or, OrderedQ, Out, Outer, Part, Partition, Piecewise,
 Plus, Position, Positive, Power, PreDecrement, PreIncrement, Prepend, PrependTo, Product,
 Quotient, Random, RandomChoice, RandomComplex, RandomInteger, RandomReal, RandomSample,
 RandomVariate, Range, Re, ReplacePart, Rest, Return, Reverse, RotateLeft, RotateRight,
 Round, RuleCondition, SameQ, Scan, Sec, Sech, SeedRandom, Select, Set, SetDelayed,
 Compile`SetIterate, Sign, Sin, Sinc, Sinh, Sort, Sqrt, Internal`Square, Internal`StuffBag,
 Subtract, SubtractFrom, Sum, Switch, Table, Take, Tan, Tanh, TensorRank, Throw, Times,
 TimesBy, Tr, Transpose, Unequal, Union, Unitize, UnitStep, UnsameQ, VectorQ, Which,
 While, With, Xor}
```

As of *Mathematica* 10.0.2, there are also the following functions:

```
{Gamma, Indexed, LogGamma, LogisticSigmoid, Internal`ReciprocalSqrt}
```

As of *Mathematica* 11, there are also the following functions:

```
{Internal`Expm1, Internal`Log1p, Ramp}
```

As of *Mathematica* 11.2, there are also the following functions:

```
{RealAbs, RealSign}
```

**About [`Tr`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html):**

Please note that [`Tr`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html) appears in this list, but cannot actually be compiled without a call to `MainEvaluate[]`. It is unclear if this is [deliberate or a bug](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29885300#29885300).

---

### Edit: additional functions

I have just discovered the symbol `` Internal`CompileValues ``, which provides various definitions and function calls needed to compile further functions not in the list above. Using the following code,

```
Internal`CompileValues[]; (* to trigger auto-load *)
ClearAttributes[Internal`CompileValues, ReadProtected];
syms = DownValues[Internal`CompileValues] /. 
    HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][Internal`CompileValues[sym_]] :> _] :>
        sym;
Complement[syms, Compile`CompilerFunctions[]]
```

we get some more compilable functions as follows:

```
{Accumulate, ConstantArray, Cross, Depth, Det, DiagonalMatrix,
Differences, NDSolve`FEM`FEMDot, NDSolve`FEM`FEMHold,
NDSolve`FEM`FEMInverse, NDSolve`FEM`FEMPart, NDSolve`FEM`FEMTDot,
NDSolve`FEM`FEMTotalTimes, NDSolve`FEM`FEMZeroMatrix, FromDigits,
Identity, IdentityMatrix, Inverse, LinearSolve, Mean, Median, Nand,
NestWhile, NestWhileList, Nor, Norm, Ordering, PadLeft, PadRight,
Permutations, Ratios, Signature, SquareWave, StandardDeviation,
Tally, Total, TrueQ, Variance}
```

Looking at the definition of `` Internal`CompileValues[sym] `` for *sym* in the list above will provide some additional information about how these functions are compiled. This can range from type information (for e.g. `Inverse`), through to an implementation in terms of lower-level functions (e.g. `NestWhileList`). One can presumably also make one's own implementations of non-compilable functions using this mechanism, giving `Compile` the ability to compile a wider range of functions than it usually would be able to.

As of *Mathematica* 10.3, there are also the following functions:

```
{DeleteDuplicates, Region`Mesh`SmallMatrixRank,
 Region`Mesh`SmallQRSolve, Region`Mesh`SmallSingularValues,
 Region`Mesh`SmallSingularValueSystem, Region`Mesh`SmallSVDSolve,
 NDSolve`SwitchingVariable}
```

As of *Mathematica* 11, there are also the following functions:

```
{NearestFunction, RegionDistanceFunction, RegionMemberFunction, RegionNearestFunction}
```

---

### Edit 2: the meaning of the second list

In response to [a recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/why-is-mainevaluate-being-used-when-linearsolve-can-be-compiled), I want to be clear that the presence of a function in the second list given above does not necessarily mean it can be compiled into a form free of `MainEvaluate` calls. If a top-level function is already highly optimized (as e.g. `LinearSolve` is), the purpose of `` Internal`CompileValues[func] `` may be solely to provide type information on the return value, assuming that this can be inferred from the types of the arguments or some other salient information. This mechanism allows more complex functions that call these highly-optimized top-level functions to be compiled more completely since there is no longer any question of what the return type may be and so further *unnecessary* `MainEvaluate` calls may be avoided. It *does not* imply that the use of `MainEvaluate` is unnecessary *to call the function itself*.

Comment: I thought I'd seen a documented list somewhere or other??

Comment: Interesting, `Total[]` isn't compilable, but `Plus` and `Apply` are...

Comment: It looks like you've found a counterexample. Indeed, ``MemberQ[Compile`CompilerFunctions[], Total] == False``, but in practice Total gets compiled down to a call to the internal kernel function `TotalAll`. Why `Total` is not included in the list, I have no idea.

Comment: @Mike There used to be a documented list somewhere on wri.com but it was removed shortly after v6 came out.  I used to have it bookmarked some years ago, but then it just vanished.

Comment: Actually whether a function is compilable or not (or what it gets compiled to) depends on the context and the argument types (see my answer for an example).

Comment: @Szabolcs: do you still have the URL? We can try checking the Wayback Machine to see if it was archived...

Comment: @J.M. No, unfortunately I lost that Firefox profile.  Also, `Compile` must have changed a *lot* since then.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, Ted Ersek posted the old list (version 3/4 vintage) on his website. See [here](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_A-K_18.html). There have been quite a few changes since then, though.

Comment: @OleksandrR. maybe that is where I remember seeing it, although I thought it was in Mma documentation.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: would you be so kind as to let me know what your concerns were and perhaps suggest how I could improve my answers in future? Many thanks.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Interesting that Internal`Bag functions are available for compile. Cool stuff. Makes me wonder if these are being used automagically under the hood when MMA compiles functions involving certain list structures---or if this is largely unexplored territory.

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 they are used in that way, yes (check out ``Internal`CompileValues[NestWhileList]``, for instance). That's actually how I first realised these were usable within the VM--noticing that they sometimes appear in the compiled bytecode. By the way, did you see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile)?

Comment: @OleksandrR. You rock! Thanks for pointing me toward that link. Do you know much about System`Utilites`Hash? I'm curious about Bags and Hashing and how the two might possibly relate. I'd also like to see more examples of how they can both be used, beyond toy examples. (But I'm afraid I don't really know enough to ask a question about them.) <--- That's me prodding you to ask a cool question or two so the rest of us can learn... :)

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 I think there is not much more to be said about ``System`Utilities`HashTable*`` beyond what I already wrote [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1029/312). That object definitely isn't related to the ``Internal`Bag``; they are totally different data structures (also, the `HashTable` cannot be used in compiled code). Hash tables and linked lists are well-known data structures in computer science, so you will find a lot of information already out there. Any more specific questions... just ask!

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, can you confirm `FromDigits` is compilable? I tried `Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}}, FromDigits[x, 2]]`, but it came out as a "MainEvaluate" (an instruction `{47, FromDigits, ...}`).

Comment: @Silvia no, `FromDigits` is not compilable. Its presence in the second list merely indicates that the compiler knows what types it accepts and returns. Namely, given an integer input of rank $n>0$, it produces an integer output of rank $n-1$.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I see. Thanks!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Can `SetDelayed` be compiled? here it seems it can't be:
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2830/can-setdelayed-be-compiled

Comment: @yashar the VM does not have the same evaluation semantics as the top-level evaluator. So, when `SetDelayed` gets compiled, its behavior will be different to that experienced in top-level code. But, the compiler does convert it to bytecode, albeit not completely faithfully, depending on the intent of the code being compiled.

Comment: A few more functions have appeared since v8, including `Indexed` and `Gamma` (updated from answers below)

Comment: Note that Gamma only supports 1 argument, rather than multiple arguments for the incomplete gamma functions. But still, nice to have.

Comment: Better way: ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[]\[Union]Keys[GeneralUtilities`DownValuesAssociation[Internal`CompileValues]]``.

Answer (score 61):

In addition to Oleks list, there is of course a way to study what happens under the hood.

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}},
   Accumulate[x]
   ];
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[f]

(*

        1 argument
        1 Integer register
        2 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(I1)0 = A1
        I0 = 4
        Result = T(I1)1

1   T(I1)1 = Accumulate[ T(I1)0, I0]]
2   Return
*)
```

Here you see, that `Accumulate` can be compiled down, the question is where does this come from? Since version 8 you can compile to C-code, so let's do this and check what happens

```
<< CCodeGenerator`
CCodeGenerate[f, "fun", "tmp.c"];
FilePrint["tmp.c"]
```

I won't copy the whole output, but inspecting the code shows you

```
FP0 = funStructCompile->getFunctionCallPointer("Accumulate");
```

So the library extracts a function pointer from another (the WolframRTL) library. This library is distributed with Mathematica and you should have it in your `SystemFiles/Libraries/$SystemID` directory. You can now study this library by using tools like `nm` (on *nix systems) showing you the exported symbols.
This is a very long list of course and maybe a bit cryptic to those not used to C-programming, but it should be readable. Here a short snip

```
00000000003327d0 T _MTensor_outerList
0000000000336e10 T _MTensor_outerPlus
00000000003352a0 T _MTensor_outerTimes
000000000032d1f0 t _MTensor_pTranspose
00000000003291b0 T _MTensor_pad
000000000032a580 T _MTensor_position
0000000000326140 T _MTensor_reallocateAndCopyData
0000000000325750 t _MTensor_releaseData
00000000003263f0 T _MTensor_resetDimensions
0000000000328f90 T _MTensor_reverse
000000000032cc80 T _MTensor_rotate
```

The question is, can you get more insight (if wanted) when inspecting this together with the list provided by Olek? I think it depends, sometimes yes, sometimes no. In my opinion, it is always nice to have a clue what's going on in the deep.

One example from the `` Compile`CompilerFunctions[] `` list is the function `Outer`. As you can see in the output above, this function does not directly exist, but is split into three forms, `outerList`, `outerPlus` and `outerTimes`. Regarding this, it seems `Outer` cannot be compiled in every form. Let's test this

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}},
   Outer[List, x, x]
   ];
CompilePrint[f]

(* 
  1 T(I3)1 = OuterList[ T(I1)0, T(I1)0, I0, I0]]
)*
```

This works as expected and we see the function `OuterList` is used. You can if you want to inspect the c-code too. Let me skip this here and try the same function with a `Divide` as head

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}},
   Outer[Divide, x, x]
   ];
(*
Compile::cpapot: Compilation of Outer[Divide,x,x] is not supported 
for the function argument Complex. The only function arguments supported 
are Times, Plus, or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
*)
```

If the error message would not point out directly, that `Outer` is only possible with the 3 heads, one could argue, that `Divide` is a bad function anyway since integers are not closed under this operation. You can easily try it with `Complex` and get the same message.

To summarize: Usually, you don't need any list of supported functions, because the rule of thumb is, that compile will not work with already optimized, complicated Mathematica-methods. This includes `NIntegrate`, `FindRoot` or `NMinimize`. Nevertheless, `Compile` can easily be used to make those function-calls really fast. What you have to do is to compile your target function, because the most time with stuff like `NIntegrate` is spent, evaluating the integrand. The same is true for `FindRoot`, `NMinimize` and many more methods.

Another good indicator to guess whether or not a function is supported is to look at the *kinds* of functions of Oleks list. There are exceptions to this rule but basically the list of supported functions can be divided into two classes. Simple numerical functions like `Sin` or `Xor` and functions which help you to work with tensors. I don't remember how often I wished I simply had `Tally`, `Map` or `Fold` in C. Even the addition or multiplication of tensors must be done manually.

Therefore, if a Mathematica-function implements a complicated method, when it's not a mathematical function or when it does not help you working with tensors/lists, it is most probably not supported by `Compile`.

Comment: +1. Regarding your `Outer` example - which is good in this context - I just want to add that it is rather special. There are good reasons why it can only be compiled for the heads you named. In this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973424/in-mathematica-how-do-i-compile-the-function-outer-for-an-arbitrary-number-of/4973603#4973603, I show how to make compilation of `Outer` more flexible, and also discuss the reasons why compiling `Outer` is tricky.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I scrolled through the list and was trying to find an really short example. It was the first catch my eye.

Answer (score 45):

**Warning:** The `SetSystemOptions` method to detect failed compilation, described below, is not 100% reliable.  Please see the comments (e.g. `trC = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 2}}, Tr[a]]` won't warn).

---

I assume you need the list of compilable functions to make sure that all of your code will be properly compiled, and it won't take any speed penalties (that why I was looking for this information before).  People have shown you how to print the compiled code and check that there are no calls to `MainEvaluate` in it.  There is an alternative and simpler way of working:

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True]
```

After setting this, `Compile` will warn about uncompilable things:

```
In[4]:= cf1 = Compile[{x}, Total[x]]

During evaluation of In[4]:= Compile::extscalar: 
  Total[x] cannot be compiled and will be evaluated externally. 
  The result is assumed to be of type Real. >>

Out[4]= CompiledFunction[{x},Total[x],-CompiledCode-]

In[5]:= cf2 = Compile[{{x,_Integer,1}}, Total[x]]

Out[5]= CompiledFunction[{x},Total[x],-CompiledCode-]
```

This is better than just thinking about which function is compilable and which isn't because as you can see, whether something can be compiled also depends on context (`Total` in this example.)

---

For completeness, let me show that `CompilePrint[cf1]` gives

```
        R0 = A1
        Result = R1

1   R1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Total][ R0]]
2   Return
```

while `CompilePrint[cf2]` gives

```
        T(I1)0 = A1
        I0 = 4
        Result = I1

1   I1 = TotalAll[ T(I1)0, I0]]
2   Return
```

Comment: Could you please comment on why `trC = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 2}}, Tr[a]]` calls `MainEvaluate` and why your method doesn't trigger an error message (after setting the appropriate system option)?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Unfortunately, I cannot.  It seems the method is not reliable.  I should update the answer.

Comment: @IstvánZachar For lack of time, I'll just put a warning at the top of the answer now.  If you have other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: @Oleksandr, Szabolcs I think the problem of not throwing an error is covered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1193/89), though why `Tr` cannot be compiled primarily without ME eludes me.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Fortunately it's relatively easy to create a compiled `Tr` alternative.

Comment: This comment only comes two years late, but... the main reason why `cf1` has a call out of the VM is IMO that the invocation of `Total` used here is an error anyway. The compiler knows this and does not compile what will end up producing an essentially useless (and not representable in the VM) result, i.e. a message and an unevaluated `Total[_]`.

Answer (score 35):

A bit late to the discussion but I had the chance to ask Wolfram's North America sales manager about this.  I had forwarded him the list of compilable functions "Compile`CompilerFunctions[]".

He asked one of his engineers about this.  They came back with some information that I thought would add to this question.

> I don't think that is the correct interpretation of the list
>   Sort[Compile`CompilerFunctions[]]. This list consists of those system
>   functions that are pre-compiled. But any numerical function can be
>   compiled to C and basically any user defined function that does not
>   use a purely symbolic function can be compiled to C, for eg:

```
In[1]:= square=Compile[{x},x^2]  
Out[1]= CompiledFunction[{x},x^2,-CompiledCode-]   

In[2]:= square /@ {1.3,3.5,6.7} 
Out[2]= {1.69,12.25,44.89}
```

> And even for symbolic functions, you can get them to evaluate before
>   compilation using `CompileEvaluate[..]`
>
> Mathematica's compiler is more powerful than other programs because it also allows for checking of types in the compiled expression.

....

**MORE FROM WOLFRAM**

As I mentioned in a comment to Oleksandr, I went back to the sales manager for a clarification.  He forwarded the issue to a senior developer.  The reply just came back and follows (with some minor formatting):

> It (compiling) is not as simple as just a list of functions.
>
> For a number of functions, some uses of the function are supported and
>   others are not.
>
> Thus, the list of functions is a starting point, but does not give the
>   whole story.   The following function is a simple test that tells you
>   if a function can be compiled to stand alone C or not:

```
Needs["CCodeGenerator`"];

SetAttributes[CCompileQ, HoldAll];
CCompileQ[args__] := Module[{cf = Compile[args]},
   Check[CCodeStringGenerate[cf, "test",
     "CodeTarget" -> "WolframRTL"]; True, False, CCodeGenerate::wmreq]]
```

> examples:

```
In[37]:= CCompileQ[{x}, x^2]
Out[37]= True

In[38]:= CCompileQ[{x}, f[x]]
Out[38]= False
```

> During evaluation of `In[38]:= CCodeGenerate::wmreq:` The expression `f`
>   requires Mathematica to be evaluated.   The function will be generated
>   but can be expected to fail with a nonzero error code when executed.
>
> Note that the message will give one instance of something in the
>   expression that could not be compiled to C.

Comment: Interesting response, but this engineer seems to be wrong. Are you sure the sales manager didn't write this (especially the last sentence) while claiming that an engineer has passed on the information? ;) Some of the listed functions are pre-compiled in the sense that there's a corresponding function in the *Mathematica* RTL that can be called directly from the VM, but there are counterexamples (e.g. `Total` which is missing from the first list even though it compiles down to a call to the internal function `TotalAll`) that show that this isn't a sufficient condition for their inclusion.

Comment: Also, many of the special functions, though numerical, cannot be compiled. `MathieuCPrime` is one that comes immediately to mind--and it even has the `NumericFunction` attribute.

Comment: @OleksandrR. -- I can go back to the sales manager with your thoughts.  I'll also ask if the engineer can visit this question.

Comment: that would be very useful, because although I don't really have any doubts about the applicability of the list as an answer to this question, it's not clear to me how it's used internally by the compiler and whether *every* compilable function is given by either ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[]`` or as a downvalue of ``Internal`CompileValues``. Information on how to modify the latter to enable the compilation of additional functions would be particularly helpful. I'm not sure who wrote the compiler but I think either Mark Sofroniou or Rob Knapp will probably be good people to ask.

Comment: @OleksandrR. -- On the case.  Will report back...

Comment: @OleksandrR. -- Not certain you still follow this question, but check out the reply I finally received from Wolfram.  Best,

Comment: So, we've progressed from "the list isn't meaningful since anything can be compiled" to "only some functions are compilable, but the list is a partial description". That's better, although I had hoped for some information to be provided that we didn't know already. Anyway, thanks very much for taking the time to inquire! (BTW, I'm not sure why they focus so much on compilation to C. Not all compilable functions can be translated to C, e.g. `Compile[{}, Label[1]; Goto[1]]`, which fails due to a bug in the ``CCodeGenerator` `` package.)

Comment: With all due respect, I think the first example given by the engineer is meaningless. `Power` is in the list of `Compile\`CompilerFunctions[] `!

Answer (score 28):

I believe there is such a list available but I can't remember the command off-hand.  In the meantime, you can always load `CompiledFunctionTools` via.

```
<<CompiledFunctionTools`
```

And then use `CompilePrint` on a compiled function to see if `MainEvaluate` is present in the pseudocode.  `MainEvaluate` tells us that something is going through the evaluator and wasn't compilable.

```
f=Compile[{{x,_Real,1}},
  Print[x];
  x
];

In[61]:= CompilePrint[f]

Out[61]= 
        1 argument
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R1)0 = A1
        Result = T(R1)0

1   V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, Print[x]][ T(R1)0]]
2   Return
```

Notice the `MainEvaluate` in the call to `Print`.  This means `Print` isn't compilable.

Answer (score 19):

The following additional functions are compilable in Mathematica 9.

```
{Gamma, LogGamma, Internal`ReciprocalSqrt}
```

Answer (score 12):

The following are compilable in M10 but aren't in previous versions:

```
{Indexed, LogisticSigmoid}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `Indexed` and it seems like a long due function

Answer (score 12):

`Span` can be compiled:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`

cf = Compile[{{lst, _Real, 1}}, lst[[;; 2]]];
CompilePrint@cf
```

[image]

*Pictured by Simon Wood's [shadow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43187/1871).*

---

`All` used as an argument of `Part` can be compiled:

```
cf2 = Compile[{{lst, _Real, 2}}, lst[[All, ;; 2]]];
CompilePrint@cf2
```

[image]

while `All` used as an argument of `Span`, which is the `FullForm` of `(* a number* ) ;;` , can't be compiled:

```
2 ;; // FullForm
```

> ```
> Span[2, All]
> ```

```
cf3 = Compile[{{lst, _Real, 1}}, lst[[2 ;;]]];
```

> Compile::cpintlt: 2;;All at position 2 of lst[[2;;All]] should be either a nonzero integer or a vector of nonzero integers; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>

---

Pure function i.e. `Function` formed by above-mentioned compilable functions can *usually* be compiled:

```
cf4 = Compile[{x}, Sin[#] &@x];
cf4 // CompilePrint
```

> ```
> ……
> 1 R1 = R0
> 2 R2 = Sin[ R1]
> ……
> ```

---

`Ordering`, which is in the 2nd list of [Oleksandr R.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/1871), can be compiled:

```
cf5 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Ordering@x];
cf5 // CompilePrint
```

> ```
> ……
> 1 T(I1)1 = Ordering[ T(R1)0]]
> ……
> ```

---

`Blank` can be compiled when it's the last pattern of `Switch`:

```
cf6 = Compile[{i}, Switch[i, 1., 100, _, 300]]    
cf6 // CompilePrint
```

> ```
> ……
> 1 B0 = R0 None R1 (tol R1)
> 2 if[ !B0] goto 5
> 3 I2 = I0
> 4 goto 6
> 5 I2 = I1
> 6 Return
> ```

You may check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127424/1871) for more information.

Comment: Surprisingly, `lst[[2 ;; -1]]` can be compiled while `lst[[2;;]]` can't. If one changes `All` in `cf2` to be `;;`, the error will show up again. This can be also got around by changing `;;` to `1;;-1` if one sticks to the shorthand notation of `Span`.

Comment: @luyuwuli That's all because of `All`, the `FullForm` of `;;` is `Span[1, All]` actually.