# Select/Delete with Sublist elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Probably easy and short question, I still didn't fully figure out how to easily select/delete sublists from a list. Example:

```
tt = {{2, 4}, {4, 8}};
```

I want to delete/select all the elements where the difference between them (`Abs`) is greater than four.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would use either

```
Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; Abs[x - y] > 4]
```

or

```
With[{diff = Abs[data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]]] - 4}, 
   Pick[data, UnitStep[diff]*Unitize[diff], 1]
]
```

The first clearly demonstrates what you are trying to do, the second is much faster...

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {10^6, 2}];

(m1 =  Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; Abs[x - y] > 4]); // AbsoluteTiming

==> {2.8393092, Null}

(m2 = 
    With[{diff = Abs[data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]]] - 4}, 
     Pick[data,UnitStep[diff]*Unitize[diff], 1]]); // AbsoluteTiming

==> {0.1248024, Null}

m1 == m2

==> True
```

Assuming you are working with random data and don't expect equality, the second method can be simplified to...

```
Pick[data, UnitStep[Abs[data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]]] - 4], 1]
```

**Edit:**

Of course if you want to delete elements where `Abs[x-y] > 4` you can modify the `Cases` definition as

```
Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; Abs[x - y] <= 4]
```

And the `Pick` method by swapping out the `1` in the last argument with `0`.

Comment: Since `UnitStep[0]==1`, you could use `Pick[data, UnitStep[4 - Abs[data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]]]], 0]` if you want the absolute value to be strictly larger than 4.

Answer (score 10):

You can select all sublists the elements of which differ by more than 3 as follows:

```
Select[tt, Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] > 3 &]
(*{{4, 8}}*)
```

or using conditional patterns:

```
Cases[tt, x_ /; Abs[x[[1]] - x[[2]]] > 3]
```

(and you can delete them by either selecting those `Not` satisfying the condition, or using `DeleteCases`).

You could also do

```
Scan[If[Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] > 3, Sow[#]] &, tt] // Reap // 
  Last // Last
```

or even

```
MapThread[If[Abs[#1 - #2] > 3, Sow[{#1, #2}]] &, Transpose@tt]; // 
   Reap // Last // Last
```

Finally using `Compile` and `` Internal`Bag ``, as described by Andy [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1942/16), you can do

```
cs = Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 2}},
   Module[{bag = Internal`Bag[], l = Length@lst},
    Do[
     If[
      Abs[lst[[i, 1]] - lst[[i, 2]]] > 3.,
      Internal`StuffBag[
       bag,
       lst[[i]], 1
       ]
      ],
     {i, l}
     ];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[bag, All], 2]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

which is roughly as fast as the `Pick` approach described in [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2488/16) (neither unpacks).

Answer (score 8):

```
Cases[tt, {a_, b_} /; Abs[a - b] >= 4]
```

> ```
>  {{4, 8}}
> ```

or

```
DeleteCases[tt, {a_, b_} /; Abs[a - b] < 4]
```

> ```
>  {{4, 8}}
> ```

The latter approach could be better if  pairs `Abs[a-b] > 4` are generic.

Answer (score 5):

I would also choose `Pick` for speed, but I would formulate it a little differently:

```
Pick[
  tt,
  UnitStep[Abs[# - #2] & @@ Transpose[tt] - 5],
  1
]
```

To pick the complement change the third argument from `1` to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Although not as fast as `Pick`, another possibility is to use `GatherBy` which allows selecting/deleting subsets of data based on a condition:

```
  data = {{2, 4}, {4, 8}, {5, 9}, {1, 3}};
  {deleted,selected}= GatherBy[data, UnitStep[Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] - 4] &]
```

returns:

```
   {{{2, 4}, {1, 3}}, {{4, 8}, {5, 9}}}
```

Comment: `GroupBy` is a useful alternative to `GatherBy`, since the result is more obvious to interpret.