# Select record when third column matches certain criterion

Tags: text, filtering

I've a table with 3 columns. The table looks like this:

```
test = {
  {"john", {"suzan", "jan"}, {"new", "job", "policies"}}, 
  {"carla", {"john", "piet"}, {"route", "suggestion"}}, 
  {"jan", {"john", "suzan"}, {"re", "new", "job", "policies"}}, 
  {"john", {"piet", "carla"}, {"re", "route", "suggestion"}}}
```

I would like to select the records with has no `re` in the third column. When I select the third column like this:

```
test1 = Select[test[[All, 3]], #[[1]] != "re" &]
```

The result is:

> ```
> {{"new", "job", "policies"}, {"route", "suggestion"}}
> ```

But I want to select also the columns one and two. When I write:

```
Select[test[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], #[[3]] != "re" &]
```

The result is empty

> ```
> {}
> ```

Who has a suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Related Q/As: [Select/Delete with Sublist elements?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2486/125) and [Filtering Lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16676/125)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some other ways:

```
Cases[test, Except[{_, _, {___, "re", ___}}]]
```

or

```
Pick[test, FreeQ[#[[3]], "re"] & /@ test]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `Select` is the right method.

```
Select[test, !MemberQ[#[[3]], "re"] &]
```

Output:

> ```
> {{"john", {"suzan", "jan"}, {"new", "job", "policies"}},
>    {"carla", {"john", "piet"}, {"route", "suggestion"}}}
> ```

Which equals line 1 and 2. The `MemberQ` functions tests the third column for strings containing `re`.

Comment: You can also use `FreeQ[#[[3]],"re"]` for the test function. (+1)