# Delete data were y = "NS" in a list with elements {x, y}

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of data `{x, y}`and not all of them have actual values. They show as `{x, "NS"}` or `{"NS",y}` or `{"NS","NS"}`. I'm trying to find a way to get rid of the sets with the "NS" so I can carry the analysis.

I am using *Mathematica* 10.

---

Here is my list of `data`, I think there is something wrong with the format because I've tried `DeleteCases`, `Select`, `Cases`... and I get "{}" as an output everytime. It might just need a simple fix, but I'm not sure what (I'm still a beginner in *Mathematica*).

```
{{{10.43, "NS"}, {10.42, "NS"}, {10.29, "NS"}, {9.03, "NS"}, {10.4, "NS"},
 {3.61, 3.69}, {5.03, 4.85}, {8.8, 6.}, {8.51, "NS"}, {8.9, 8.7}, {"NS", "NS"}, 
 {6.49, 7.}, {7.32, 7.54}, {7.67, 8.17}, {9.23, "NS"}, {9.36, 9.38}, {9.3, "NS"}, 
 {8.94, 9.34}, {8.7, 8.79}, {8.41, 8.17}, {8.51, 8.58}, {8.66, 8.62}, {8.36, 8.28}, 
 {8.36, 8.38}, {8.77, 8.79}, {10.49, 10.51}, {8.33, 8.22}, {8.41, 8.18}, {8.81, 8.42}, 
 {4.92, 4.87}, {6.08, 6.21}, {6.19, 6.26}, {7.16, 7.31}, {"NS", "NS"}}}
```

Comment: Did you try [DeleteCases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html?q=DeleteCases)?

Comment: See possible duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/select-delete-with-sublist-elements, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16676/filtering-lists-in-mathematica

Comment: Re: your update example. Look at your list. It's not a list of lists, it's a list of a list of lists... you need to use the method(s) with appropriate level spec, or change the list (First@, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I noticed as soon as I posted the data that there was an extra set of "{}"

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 3}, {1, "NS"}, {"NS", 5}, {"NS", "NS"}}

Cases[list, {__?NumericQ}]
```

gives:

```
{{1, 3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {10, "NS"}, {7, 6}, {4, 5}, {"NS", "NS"}, {7, 
2}, {"NS", 9}, {9, 10}};

Select[list, AllTrue[#, NumericQ] &]
```

gives

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {7, 6}, {4, 5}, {7, 2}, {9, 10}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Karsten 7 mentioned, you can use DeleteCases like this:

```
DeleteCases[{{x, "NS"} , {"NS", y} , {"NS", "NS"}},x_String | {__String},-1]
```

Another way you can use Replace.

```
{{x, "NS"} , {"NS", y} , {"NS", "NS"}} //. _String | {} :> Sequence[]
```

Both give:

```
(*{{x}, {y}}*)
```

Comment: the levelspec has to by a positive Integer at DeleteCases.

Comment: and i think he dont wants to have single x or y values, only valid pairs {x,y} i guess.

Answer (score -3):

```
Select[list, (#[[1]]!= "NS") && (#[[2]]!= "NS") &]
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt at an answer! Could you perhaps add a bit more explaining your approach and (ideally) how it compares to others? What if the non-numeric element isn't exactly "NS"?