# Picking certain pairs according to a condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm a Mathematica beginner and can't find out a solution to my problem. I have a list of pairs of numbers, for example something like this, but much longer: list={{2., 3.}, {3., 2.}, {5., 4.}, {4., 0.}, {5., 0.}, {5., 0.}, {4., 
  0.}, {5., 4.}}. And now I need to get only pairs for which some rule is true. For example, I'd like Mathematica to give me pairs {x,y} from the aforementioned list, where x=5 and y is any. So in this case I'd get pairs {5., 4.},{5., 0.},{5., 0.} and {5., 4.}. Is there any way to do this? Thanks :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `Select`. With

```
list = {{2., 3.}, {3., 2.}, {5., 4.}, {4., 0.}, {5., 0.}, {5.,0.}, {4., 0.}, {5., 4.}}
```

you can say:

```
Select[list, #[[1]] == 5. &]
```

to get those that start with `5.`

Comment: Wow, that was quick! :) Thank you very much :))

Comment: There are a lot of very powerful functions in Mathematica -- it is worth reading some of the help files (place the cursor on the word and hit F1) to see how they are used.

Comment: This question is relevant http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/select-delete-with-sublist-elements

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
lis = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 4}};
```

then:

```
Cases[lis, {5, _}]
```

> {{5, 4}, {5, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 4}}

---

As an aside, it is better to leave your list with exact symbolic numbers like {4,5} in *Mathematica* ... and not to convert them into 'approximate' numerical numbers like (4., 5.) ... unless you have a very good reason for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Pick`, for a large list it would be more faster.

```
list = {{2., 3.}, {3., 2.}, {5., 4.}, {4., 0.}, {5., 0.}, {5.,  0.}, {4., 0.}, {5., 4.}};
Pick[#, #[[All, 1]], 5.] &@list
(*{{5., 4.}, {5., 0.}, {5., 0.}, {5., 4.}}*)


ls = RandomInteger[10, {10^6, 2}];

r1 = Pick[#, #[[All, 1]], 5] &@ls; // Timing
r2 = Select[ls, #[[1]] == 5 &]; // Timing
r3 = Cases[ls, {5, _}]; // Timing
r1 == r2 == r3

(*
{0.062400, Null}
{3.603623, Null}
{1.263608, Null}
True
*)
```