# Removing elements of a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I want removing elements of a table. For example, I have the next table:

```
data = {{0, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 8}, {7, 4}};
```

and I want removing all elements where the 1st element of sublist is between 6 and 2 for I obtain this new table:

```
data = {{0, 3}, {1, 3}, {6, 8}, {7, 4}};
```

The next code don´t work:

```
DeleteCases[data, Flatten[Select[data, 6 > #[[1]] > 2 &]]]
```

If only I want removing one element (for example {0,3}), the code work:

```
DeleteCases[data, Flatten[Select[data, 1 > #[[1]] >= 0 &]]]
```

How can I remove elements where the 1st element of sublist is between two values?.

Comment: There has got to be a dupe for this, but in the meantime: why not stick to `Select`? E.g. `Select[data, Not[6 > #[[1]] > 2] &]`.

Comment: DeleteCases[data,x/;(x[[1]]>xmin&&x[[1]]<xmax)] where xmin and xmax are your thresholds for first element

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2486/5478

Comment: The second argument of DeleteCases must be a pattern.  I recommend reading through some of these chapters: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html

Comment: Why `{6,8}` is left but `{2,5}` is not.

Comment: The code of  @MariusLadegård work and is simple for I want it . Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba, sorry, I want to say <=6 and >2.

Answer (score 4):

You can pick the desired elements, e.g.

```
Pick[data, 2 <= #[[1]] < 6 & /@ data, False]
Pick[data, Not[2 <= #[[1]] < 6] & /@ data]
```

or deleting:

```
DeleteCases[data, {_?(2 <= # < 6 &), _}]
```

Comment: When I import table of a file with two columns (x,y) I have    data = {{{0, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 8}, {7, 4}}}. In these case only work the @MarkusDichtl code. I don´t understand why.

Comment: @Manu  I am sorry I do not understand your comment. In my timezone I am off to sleep. I will aim to look after I get up but I am certain other uses will resolve :)

Comment: @Manu. In that case, replace `data` in ubpdqn's code with `First@data`, and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

New approach since v10.2:

```
data /. {x_ /; 6 > x >= 2, y_} -> Nothing
```

and `Nothing` just vanishes, resulting in

> ```
> {{0, 3}, {1, 3}, {6, 8}, {7, 4}}
> ```

Comment: In the version 10 work too.

Comment: `Nothing` was introduced in 10.2, it's a special symbol for the standard evaluation process.