# I have a list of 175 elements. Each element contains two numbers. I want to pick those elements which have both the number greater than 2? How?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of 175 elements. Each element contains two numbers. I want to pick those elements which have both the number greater than 2? How?[image]

Comment: As an example: `data = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {175, 2}];` and `Select[data, (First@# > 2 && Last@# > 2) &]`

Comment: @Syed One could also do something like `data // Select[AllTrue[# > 2 &]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a list

```
list = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {10, 2}]
```

> {{8.25097, 4.41379}, {4.96729, 3.19113}, {1.31825, 6.73581}, {9.18737,
> 9.23329}, {2.27443, 2.6997}, {1.86022, 5.05654}, {8.64963,
> 7.68031}, {2.03275, 4.07207}, {3.50992, 3.56807}, {6.78094, 8.9849}}

### Some possible ways are the following:

- 0. [`Compile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) + `` Internal`Bag `` following the answer by [Andy Ross](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/efficiently-collecting-results-inside-a-compiled-function/1942#1942)

The code is:

```
ib = Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 2}}, 
   Module[{bag = Internal`Bag[], l = Length@lst}, 
    Do[If[lst[[i, 1]] > 2 && lst[[i, 2]] > 2., 
      Internal`StuffBag[bag, lst[[i]], 1]], {i, l}];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[bag, All], 2]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

and then

```
ib[list]
```

- 1. [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) + [`Except`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html)

the command is:

```
Cases[list, Except[{a_, b_} /; a < 2 || b < 2]]
```

- 2. [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)

the command is:

```
DeleteCases[list, {a_, b_} /; a < 2 || b < 2]
```

- 3. [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

the command is:

```
Select[list, #[[1]] > 2 && #[[2]] > 2 &][[ ;; ]]
```

- 4. [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) --- in addition to what Michael already showed

the command is:

```
Pick[list, #[[1]] > 2 && #[[2]] > 2 & /@ list][[ ;; ]]
```

- 5. [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)

the command is:

```
True /. GroupBy[list, #[[1]] > 2 && #[[2]] > 2 &]
```

- 6. [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) + [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) + [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)

the command is:

```
MapThread[If[#1 > 2 && #2 > 2, Sow[{#1, #2}]] &, Transpose@list]; // 
   Reap // Last // Last
```

- 7. [`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html) + [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) + [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)

the command is:

```
Scan[If[#[[1]] > 2 && #[[2]] > 2, Sow[#]] &, list] // Reap // 
  Last // Last
```

---

All of the above give the result

> {{8.25097, 4.41379}, {4.96729, 3.19113}, {9.18737, 9.23329}, {2.27443,
> 2.6997}, {8.64963, 7.68031}, {2.03275, 4.07207}, {3.50992,
> 3.56807}, {6.78094, 8.9849}}

Comment: (+1) But I feel this Q must have been asked before...

Comment: @MichaelE2 seems very plausible to be honest. It's a common framework with lists. Maybe people will mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: They seem to be just trying to close it. :)  Ah, me.  Sometimes hard to find these things...

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am gonna be honest here. I did not even try to find if a duplicate exists. I like my rep points going up. And yes, I am horrible human being

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this:

```
Pick[data, Min[#] > 2 & /@ data]
```

Or this is faster, not that it matters on a short list:

```
Pick[data, UnitStep[2 - (Min /@ data)], 0]
```

Comment: (+1) But I feel this Q must have been asked before...
(sorry, I am horrible, but in my head was such an obvious joke :-) )

Comment: @Rabbit Thanks. (It's `0` it needed, I believe).

Answer (score 5):

And why not ...

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {100, 2}];
reg = ImplicitRegion[x > 2 && y > 2, {x, y}]
result = Pick[data, RegionMember[reg, #] & /@ data]
```

Visualization:

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[reg, Frame -> True
  , PlotRange -> {{-1, 12}, {-1, 12}}
  , PlotStyle -> Yellow
  ]
 , Graphics[{
   Darker@Green, AbsolutePointSize[6]
   , Point@result
   , Red, Point@Complement[data, result]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) that's pretty cool. On the plus side you also win on visualizing the data.

Comment: +1 for the nice visualization but why there is one red dot and green dot on the left side of the region?

Comment: Oh, I see, this is decided by the `RegionMember`. The dots are in their correct regions but appear to be hovering on the wrong side of the line. I have included `SeedRandom` so you can filter those points and see. Filter points from x=1.99 to x=2.01 to begin with. One advantage of using regions is that you can filter points using arbitrarily defined  geometric regions for which equations may be hard to write.

Comment: @hana `Select[data, First@# > 1.99 && First @# < 2.01 &]` gives these two points. {{2.00422, 4.1762}, {1.99353, 3.1896}}. One should be in red and the other should be green.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.