# How to convert output of a For loop into a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have written a For loop in my Mathematica notebook. This For loop, when activated, will generate a sequence something like:

```
    0.1
    Null
    0.3
    0.4
    Null
    0.6
```

etc. The output solely consists of numbers and nulls.

**What I want to do is plot these values generated by my For loop, using ListPlot**. However, to use ListPlot I must first have a list, and the output of my For loop isn't in the form a list. How can I convert the output of my For loop into a list?

(Note: My For loop generates a large amount of numbers, so it is too laborious to manually enter these values into a list one by one).

My For loop is:

```
    For[i = 0,  i <1000,  i++,
       Print[
             For[n = 100, n < 600, n++,
                If[Abs[Nest[f, i*StepSize1, n] - 0.51304]<0.0001, 
                   {Print[i* StepSize1], Break[]}, {Indeterminate, Break[]}]
                ] 
            ]
      ]
```

StepSize is pre-defined, by the way.

Comment: Have a look at `Map`.

Comment: You have a whole set of tools in Mma to avoid using `For[]`loops. Consider them as a last resource.

Comment: The first rule about using `For` loops in _Mathematica_ is that you don't use `For` loops =)

Comment: The second rule about using `For` loops in _Mathematica_ is that you do not use `For` loops ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind about loops: `For` doesn't localize its iterator, while `Do` does. Thus, it's usually better to use `Do` to avoid problem (eg when using `i` as an iterator and calling a function that also uses `i` internally without localizing it). To build up the list, one can use `Sow` and `Reap`. Thus:

```
Do[Sow[5 + i], {i, 1, 10}] // Reap // Last // Last
(*{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}*)
```

Here's what I mean by localizing. Compare:

```
ClearAll[i, j]
Do[Sow[5 + i], {i, 1, 10}];
For[j = 1, j < 10, j++, Sow[5 + j]];
i
j
(*
i
10
*)
```

They do the same thing, but `For` uses a global variable; `Do` does something like using `Block`.

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't use `AppendTo` as in VF1's answer, as it creates a copy each time you add an additional element, thus making it terribly inefficient as the list grows. As others have noted, it is almost always possible to avoid an explicit `For` loop by using constructs such as `Map`, `Apply`, `Table` or the `Listable` attribute for functions. In any case, I'll answer the question as stated, because it is sometimes necessary to use a `For` loop (or `Do`) if you need to do some index gymnastics or use in a compiled function.

The most straightforward way would be to use `Reap` and `Sow` (see the documentation for examples). However, these cannot be compiled. For use in a compiled function, you can use the undocumented `` Internal`Bag `` and associated functions to get the job done. As a simple example:

```
With[{bag = Internal`Bag[]},
    For[i = 0, i < 10, i++, Internal`StuffBag[bag, i]];
    Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
]
(* {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} *)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762) by Daniel Lichtblau for a brief description of bags. These are (on purpose) undocumented, and pieces from answers here and there are all we have to go on. The key points from that answer:

> These functions live in the `` Internal` `` context.
>
> - `Bag` creates an expression bag, optionally with preset elements.
> - `BagPart` obtains parts of an expression bag, similar to `Part` for ordinary expressions. It can also be used on the lhs, e.g. to reset a value.
>     `StuffBag` appends elements to the end of a bag.
> - We also have a `BagLength`, which is useful for iterating over a bag.
>
> These functions are extrememly useful for two reasons.
>
> - First, this is a good way to make an extensible table in *Mathematica*.
> - Second, the contents of bags are evaluated but then placed in a raw expression, hence are shielded. Thus one can use these as "pointers"
>     (in the C sense) rather than as objects, and this requires no `Hold`
>     etc.

Comment: Since you mention ``Internal`Bag``s along with compiling, it's important to note that these very general objects actually have rather strict limitations on their use in compiled code that are not obvious from the functional overview, requiring some experimentation to discover. @halirutan and I discussed this [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks, I forgot about that one.

Answer (score 3):

A `For` loop is generally avoidable in *Mathematica* for these purposes by using `Table` or `Array`, which generate a list of values automatically.  There may be an extreme case, however, when you absolutely have to use a `For` loop (but I doubt it).  In that case, do this:

```
Reap@For[i=0, i < 5, i++,
        Sow[someFunctionThatGeneratesNumbersOrNull[i]];
     ]//Last//First
```

Comment: Even if you use the `For` loop, using `AppendTo` is one of the worst things possible. One can instead use `Sow` and `Reap` to collect intermediate results, or use linked lists.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin what's wrong with `AppendTo`?

Comment: @VF1: I think AppendTo creates a copy of the list with one extra item, so creating a list with length n using AppendTo is an O(n^2) operation

Comment: @nikie is exactly right. See also [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node298.html)

Comment: @VF1 I can't fully understand your syntax. The For loop I have written isn't defined like a function is (i.e in the form f[x_]:= "Whatever") so what do I insert into the part of your code where you have someFunctionThatGeneratesNumersorNull[i]?

Comment: @nikie creating a copy should be `O(n)`, no? Also, I'm pretty sure MMA uses smart arrays to store lists.

Comment: @Mel Well, why don't you post your `For` loop?  Also, please consider `Array`.

Comment: @VF1 I'll post my For loop so, in essence what I'm trying to do is find out whether or not a certain point x0 converges to 0.51304 as it is iterated using f(x) a large number of times.

Comment: @Mel There's a function for that... `FixedPoint` (or `Nest`, if you want to do it a certain number of times)

Comment: @Mel, I see your `For` loop.  Everywhere you have `Print`, place a `Sow`.  On the outside, place a `Reap`.  Or, if you're concerned with speed, use the internal stuff as rm-rf recommends.

Comment: @VF1 creating a copy is $O(n)$. But in building a list of $O(n)$ length by successively appending, you copy $O(n)$ times. Hence $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @OleksandrR.  I see.  I thought he was referring to just `AppendTo`.