# Documentation of the frequently-used functions in the context of Internal` and Compile`

Tags: documentation, reference-request, undocumented

In this site, I have gradually found out that there is a collection of functions in all kinds of answers. For instance, `` Compile`GetElement ``, `` Internal`Bag ``,etc. However, these functions are undocumented.

- `` Compile`GetElement ``  see this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61509/has-this-implementation-of-fdm-touched-the-speed-limit-of-mathematica/61597#61597)
- `` Internal`Bag ``  see this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/how-to-convert-output-of-a-for-loop-into-a-list/14357#14357)

For example

```
 ?Compile`*
```

> [image]

```
 ?Internal`*
```

> [image]

---

#### Question

Is it possible to have a documentation of these ***frequently-used*** functions with the help of the users in this community?

Like the styles as follow

- [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)
- [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)

For example, using the following style:

> - function[arg1,arg2] realize the functionality ....
> - Basic Usage Example

Comment: @ShutaoTang It seems to me that this question could be merged with [(805)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/121).  Would you make the case for *not* merging these, please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, OK, but I don't know how to merge it to (805). So please help me do this operation.:)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Yes, now I think my question indeed is a *subset* of question(*805*) that you linked.

Comment: @ShutaoTang After the bounty has completed I shall close the question as a duplicate and post in Chat; if no one objects I shall perform the (irreversible) Merge to move the answers from this question to the master and redirect users to that question.