# Compiling Map over expression that yields a ragged array

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, tensors

I'm trying to speed up a function that looks in the neighborhood of each 3D point in a large dataset and finds all the points within 1 unit in each direction, x, y, z.

I've started by using `Select` to find the points around a specified point and then `Map` this function over the dataset.

First, lets make up some "data" and then define the `findpoints` function.

```
data = RandomReal[10, {10^4, 3}];

findpoints[data_, pt_]:= Block[{x = pt[[1]], y = pt[[2]], z = pt[[3]]},  
  Select[data, 
   x - 1 <= #[[1]] <= x + 1 && y - 1 <= #[[2]] <= y + 1 && 
     z - 1 <= #[[3]] <= z + 1 &]
]
```

Now lets map it over the random data.

```
Map[findpoints[data, #] &, data]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This is quite slow, I gave up waiting, so I started by compiling the `findpoint` function.

```
findpointsC = 
  Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {pt, _Real, 1}}, 
   Block[{x = pt[[1]], y = pt[[2]], z = pt[[3]]}, 
    Select[data, 
     x - 1 <= #[[1]] <= x + 1 && y - 1 <= #[[2]] <= y + 1 && 
       z - 1 <= #[[3]] <= z + 1 &]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

output= Map[findpointsC[data, #] &, data]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{3.7542147, Null}*)
```

Much faster, great.

Now I figured since compiling was so beneficial here and in other functions I found that by compiling the `Map` function I can gain some more speed, lets compile the whole thing.

```
mapfindpointsC = 
  Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}}, Map[findpointsC[data, #] &, data], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

mapfindpointsC[data]

(*CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>*)
```

However, as per the error message, in this case the output is ragged.

```
TensorQ[output]

(*False*)
```

I've tried to flatten the output from map but nothing I can think of works. Is it possible to compile this expression.

Comment: apart from the ragged thing, try `CompilePrint[mapfindpointsC]` and you'll see that, because `findpointsC` is defined externally, this doesn't really compile everything (or anything really).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please compare

```
Map[findpointsC[data, #] &, data]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.567939, Null} *)
```

and

```
findpointsC[data, data] ; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.841954, Null} *)
```

And of course is

```
Map[findpointsC[data, #] &, data] == findpointsC[data, data] 
(* True *)
```

The explanation is simple: You *typed* `RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}` and `Parallelization` but you have not used it.

### Explanation for your error message

The problem with your `Map` arises because `Compile`d functions can only work with rectangular arrays. Since every point has (most likely) a different number of points in its neighborhood, the result array is *ragged*, or *not rectangular*.

It's not enough to use `Flatten` because even then, you still create such a ragged array. One (slower) way out of this is to collect all points in a linear list, but then you loose the information, which point-set was created by which point. This cannot be the goal, if the solution is as simple as described above. Anyway, as you might have seen we had a topic here about `` Internal`Bag `` which can be used to collect an unknown number of elements. Please see the discussion in the thread

[Internal`Bag inside Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/187)

Based on this, you could make an all in one compiled function which I only give for reference and not for usage. It is much slower than the `Listable` approach.  I use the already compiled function `findpointsC` by using `With` and giving the option

```
CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
```

I have replaced your `Map` with a `Do` loop which runs over all points and finds the nearest neighbors. To insert such a list of points into an `` Internal`Bag `` we have to `Flatten` it which can be done with the 3rd parameter of `` Internal`StuffBag ``. To reshape the flat list at the end into a list of points I use `Partition`

```
mapfindpointsC =
 With[{fpC = findpointsC},
  Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}},
   Module[{result = Internal`Bag[Most[{.0}]]},
    Do[Internal`StuffBag[result, fpC[data, pt], 2], {pt, data}];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[result, All], 3]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}]
]

mapfindpointsC[data]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {3.831499, Null} *)
```