# How to generate apart or non-intersecting spheres in cube?

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to generate model of randomly distributed uniform spheres in the cube. For randomly distributed spheres I am using `RandomReal` option. But when I run the program I obtain a cube with several spheres located either inside each other or have intersections. Is there any way to make them apart and non-intersecting?

Here is a code of this problem:

```
cube = {Opacity[0.3], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {20, 20, 20}]};
spheres = Table[{Green, Sphere[RandomReal[{1, 20-1}, 3], 1]}, {j, 1, 100}];
gr = Graphics3D[{cube, spheres}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'd use the code from the bottom of [The Mathematica One-Liner Competition](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/17/the-mathematica-one-liner-competition/) :p

Comment: With your code I only see an average of about 3 collisions. Generate perhaps 110 spheres, eliminate collisions from the list and take the first 100. Should take you a fraction of a second and you are done. That probably slightly dirties your uniform distribution, but probably not enough to be able to detect.

Comment: [5478](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2594/5478)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

Keep a list of the locations you add - draw from a uniform distribution and only add to the list if it doesn't overlap.

```
cube = {Opacity[0.3], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {20, 20, 20}]};

newLocation[existing_]:= Module[{try,count=1},
  While[
    try=RandomReal[{1,19},3];
    Min[EuclideanDistance[try,#[[1]]]&/@existing]<2,
    count++
  ];
  {try,count}
]

makeLocations[n_]:=Module[{list={},loc},
  Do[
    loc=newLocation[list];
    AppendTo[list,loc],
    {n}
  ];
  list
]

spheres={Green,Sphere[#[[1]],1]&/@makeLocations[100]};

gr = Graphics3D[{cube, spheres}]
```

Comment: But does take quadratic time :(

Comment: You could use [this idea](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20946/193)

Comment: You could use octtrees perhaps if you needed to optimize the search for overlapping spheres.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping. Bakha