# How to compile the code for generate Pythagorean_triple?

Tags: programming, compile

I am finding [Pythagorean_triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), it worked slowly. I tried to compile, but it gives some warnings. 
I also use "Case" or "Do" ,both of them failed.I'm sure my CCompiler has been set correctly.
How can I compile the following code?

```
With[{m = 200},
 Select[Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, m}, {y, x, m}, {z, y, m}], 
   2], (#1^2 + #2^2 == #3^2 &) @@ # &]
 ]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are much faster ways to generate Pythagorean triples.

**Update: Now twice as fast**.

```
genPTunder[lim_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{prim},
  prim =
   Join @@ Table[
     If[CoprimeQ[m, n], {2 m n, m^2 - n^2, m^2 + n^2}, ## &[]],
     {m, 2, Floor @ Sqrt @ lim},
     {n, 1 + m ~Mod~ 2, m, 2}
   ];
  Union @@ (Range[lim ~Quotient~ Max@#] ~KroneckerProduct~ {Sort@#} & /@ prim)
 ]

genPTunder[50]
```

> ```
> {{3, 4, 5}, {5, 12, 13}, {6, 8, 10}, {7, 24, 25}, {8, 15, 17},
>  {9, 12, 15}, {9, 40, 41}, {10, 24, 26}, {12, 16, 20}, {12, 35, 37},
>  {14, 48, 50}, {15, 20, 25}, {15, 36, 39}, {16, 30, 34}, {18, 24, 30},
>  {20, 21, 29}, {21, 28, 35}, {24, 32, 40}, {27, 36, 45}, {30, 40, 50}}
> ```

```
genPTunder[100000] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.125, 161436}
> ```

Over 160,000 triples in an eighth of a second should be serviceable, even without compilation.

Comment: I think OP is trying to figure out the mistake in his code…still +1 for the unbelievable fast code :D.

Comment: @xzczd perhaps, but why fix what *will remain broken* (slow) when there is a better alternative? :^)

Answer (score 7):

Here is one idea; with more time one could think of a better way to generate the table.

```
ccheck = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},   list[[1]]^2 + list[[2]]^2 == list[[3]]^2, CompilationTarget :> "C"]

pt = Compile[{{m, _Integer}}, 
 Select[Select[Tuples[{Range[m], Range[m], Range[m]}], #[[1]] <= #[[2]] <= #[[3]] &], 
        ccheck[#] &], {{ccheck[_], True | False}}, 
  CompilationTarget :> "C"]

output1 = With[{m = 200}, Select[Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, m}, {y, x, m}, {z, y, m}], 2], (#1^2 + #2^2 == #3^2 &) @@ # &]] // AbsoluteTiming;

output2 = pt[200] // AbsoluteTiming;

output1[[1]]
(* 8.918892 *)

output2[[1]]
(* 1.250000 *)

output1[[2]]==output2[[2]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: You have to check your compiled code. It still calls the kernel. Solve this by (1) using `With` in combination with `CompilationOptions->{"InlineCompiledFunctions"->True}` to really inline `ccheck`. (2) Don't use `Tuples` inside `Compile`. Use it outside and give the built tuples to the compiled function. This saves some tenth seconds.

Answer (score 6):

I already knew a fast way, but I didn't know how to let it gives a list.

```
cpt = Compile[{{m, _Integer}},
   Do[If[i^2 + j^2 == k^2, Print[{i, j, k}]], {i, m}, {j, i, m}, {k, j, m}],
      CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

cpt[1000] // Timing
```

==============================

update, a neat version, but it's not my original:

```
  ptc = Compile[{{m, _Integer}},
   Do[If[i^2 + j^2 == k^2, Sow@{i, j, k}], {i, m}, {j, i, m}, {k, j, m}], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

 ptc[1000] // Reap // Last // First // Length // Timing
(*{0.359, 881}*)
```

Comment: Have a look at ``Internal`Bag`` here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile

Comment: +1 for learning to use `Sow` and `Reap`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ``Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint@ptc``  ... Strange that the calls to `MainEvalute` don't seem to slow things down too much...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a compiled version of the for loop:

```
PTG[m_] := 
  Select[Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, m}, {y, x, m}, {z, y, m}], 
    2], #[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2 == #[[3]]^2 &];
PTGC = Compile[{{m, _Integer}},
   Block[{list = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]]}, 
    Do[If[i^2 + j^2 == k^2, 
      Internal`StuffBag[list, {i, j, k}, 2]], {i, m}, {j, i, m}, {k, j, m}];
    Internal`BagPart[list, All]
    ], CompilationTarget -> C, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Here are some timings (the last one is @b.gatessucks solution):

```
PTG[200] // Length // Timing
Partition[PTGC[200], 3] // Length // Timing
pt[200] // Length // Timing

(*
{5.741, 127}
{0., 127}
{0.78, 127}
*)
```

(But of course I'd go with mr.W solution) 
(I was to lazy to add `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`, but in this case it really helps)

Comment: Hmm, strange, If I run it like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx1QX.png) or [in it's own](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QRag5.png) cell I get different timings. I think I'll have to improve the benchmarking for this case, but don't have time now

Comment: Re: benchmarking, search for `timeAvg`

Answer (score 1):

This generates all *primitive* pythagorean triples:

```
pythT[triple_] := 
triple.# & /@ {{{1, 2, 2}, {-2, -1, -2}, {2, 2, 3}}, {{1, 2, 2}, 
{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 3}}, {{-1, -2, -2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 3}}}
pythT2[triples_] := Join[Flatten[pythT@# & /@ triples, 1], triples]
pythN[n_] := Join[{{3, 4, 5}}, DeleteDuplicates[Sort@Nest[pythT2, pythT@
{3, 4, 5}, n]]]

Last@pythN@10

(*{927538921, 927538920, 1311738121}*)
```

but it grows like `pythNlength[n_] := (3^(n + 2) - 1)/2`, so only very low `n` is needed.