# Updating a parameter each time step within a Finite Difference scheme?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, syntax, finite-difference-method

So I am solving a PDE for a function $h(\theta,t)$ via finite difference scheme. The PDE has a function $Q$ in it, which I wish to update each time step depending on where $h$ lies.

Firstly, let us look at simple case when $Q = const$. Here is my code:

```
ClearAll[dh, t, n, ds, h0, sol, h, valh, ti, s];

n = 1001;
ds = Pi/(n - 1);

(* dh: R^n \[Rule] R^n, symbolic and numeric *)
dh[h_List /; Length@h == n] := With[{

    s = Array[# &, n, {-π, 0}],
    Q = 0.005,(*I wish to update this each time step depending on \
where h lies.*)
    d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/ds, #] &,
    d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/ds^2, #] &,
    h2 = Join[{2}, h, {2}]
    }, (-2 + h) (-1 + 
      h) (-18 Q d1[h2] + (-2 + h) (-1 + h) (4 + h (-15 + 8 h)) Cos[
        s] d1[h2] + (-2 + h) (-1 + 
         h) ((-9 + 6 h) d1[h2]^2 - (2 - 3 h + h^2) (h - d2[h2])) Sin[
        s])
   ];

(*h0 ∈ R^n *)
h0 = Table[Piecewise[{

     {1.999, -Pi < θ < -7 Pi/8},
     {(2 Sin[-6 Pi/7])/
       Sin[θ], -6 Pi/
         7 < θ < -2.0909003694838066`}, {1.001, \
-2.26998149133592` < θ < -0.6662394324925154`},
     {(2 Sin[-(Pi/10)])/
       Sin[θ], -0.6662394324925154` < θ < -(Pi/10)},
     {1.999, -(Pi/8) < θ < 0}

     }, 1.999]

   , {θ, -1. Pi, 0., ds}
   ];

(*Solve 
dh/dt(t) = dh(t)
h(0)= h0

for h(t) ∈ R^n
for t ∈ (0,20)
*)
sol = With[{
    h = h[#][t] & /@ Range@n
    },

   NDSolveValue[
    {
     D[h, t] == dh[h],
     (h /. t -> 0) == h0
     },
    Head /@ h,
    {t, 0, 20}
    ]

   ];

valh = Transpose[#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ sol];
ti = Flatten@sol[[1]]["Grid"];
s = Array[# &, n, {-Pi, 0}];

h = ListInterpolation[valh, {ti, s}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

ListAnimate@Table[
  Show[
   (*Interface*)
   PolarPlot[
    Evaluate[h[ti, θ]],
    {θ, -π, 0},

    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
    ImageSize -> Large,
    PlotStyle -> Black],
   (*Ring*)
   RegionPlot[
    1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4,
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},

    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1], AspectRatio -> 1
    ]

   ]
  , {ti, 0, 20, 0.2}]
```

[image]

As we can see the interface moves around with a fixed motion, due to Q being fixed at 0.005. However, in reality I wish to update $Q$ at each time step with the following relation $Q = \cos \psi - \cos \phi$, where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the angles from the base of the annulus to the middle of the right and left flat sections.

[image]

Now I use the following pattern matching code to find the initial $Q$. It basically looks for the median position of the centre of the interface and multiply by `ds` to convert it to an angle.

```
Q = N@Cos[Median@Position[h0[[1 ;; 500]], x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999] ds][[1]] - N@Cos[(Median@
  Position[h0[[501 ;; 1001]], x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999]) ds][[1]]
```

This gives me a sensible initial $Q$ of 0.26. I wish to then update this $Q$ with each time step, with the new position of the middle of the interface. My hope is eventually that the two angles will become equal and $Q = 0$. Here is my attempt to update $Q$ at each time step in the Finite Difference scheme.

```
n = 1001;
ds = Pi/(n - 1);
ClearAll[dh, t];
dh[h_List] := 
  With[{s = Array[# &, n, {-π, 0}],
    Q = N@Cos[Median@Position[#[[1 ;; 500]], x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999] ds][[1]]-N@Cos[(Median@Position[#[[501 ;; 1001]], x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999]) ds[[1]] &,
    d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/ds, #] &,  
    d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/ds^2, #] &},
    (-2 + h) (-1 + h) (-18 Q[#1] d1[#1] + (-2 + h) (-1 + h) (4 + h (-15 + 8 h)) Cos[
      s] d1[#1] + (-2 + h) (-1 + 
       h) ((-9 + 6 h) d1[#1]^2 - (2 - 3 h + h^2) (h - 
          d2[#1])) Sin[s]) &@Join[{2}, h, {2}]];
```

Which runs, but nothing moves! It should really as the initial $Q$ for $h_0$ is 0.26 as shown before.

Any pointers on how to update $Q$ at each time step? I feel like I'm nearly there but perhaps my syntax is incorrect? Maybe using the pure function incorrectly?

Any help appreciated as always.

**Edit**

So another idea I had was to include $Q$ as an unknown in the finite difference scheme. ie. It would appear as `Q[1]`, `Q[2]` etc. in each of the equations. I could then solve the finite difference scheme `D[h,t] == dh[h,Q]` coupled with an equation for $Q$, in the `NDSolveValue`. Here is my attempt:

```
n = 1001;
ds = Pi/(n - 1);
ClearAll[dh, t];
dh[h_List, Q_] := 
  With[{s = Array[# &, n, {-π, 0}],
     d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/ds, #] &, 
     d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/ds^2, #] &},
(-2 + h) (-1 + 
     h) (-18 Q d1[#1] + (-2 + h) (-1 + h) (4 + h (-15 + 8 h)) Cos[
       s] d1[#1] + (-2 + h) (-1 + 
        h) ((-9 + 6 h) d1[#1]^2 - (2 - 3 h + h^2) (h - 
           d2[#1])) Sin[s]) &@Join[{2}, h, {2}]];

q0 = 0.26

Clear@h;
sol = With[{h = h[#][t] & /@ Range@n, Q = Q[#][t] & /@ Range@n}, 
NDSolveValue[{D[h, t] == dh[h, Q], 
  Q[t] == -N@
      Cos[(Median@
           Position[h[[501 ;; 1001]], 
            x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999]) ds][[1]] + 
    N@Cos[Median@
         Position[h[[1 ;; 500]], 
          x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999] ds][[1]] , (h /. t -> 0) == 
   h0, (Q /. t -> 0) == q0}, Head /@ h, {t, 0, 20}, 
 Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]];
```

But this gives me a very strange error.

> `Transpose::nmtx`: The first two levels of `` {NDSolve`xs$422676, NDSolve`xs$422677, NDSolve`xs$422678, NDSolve`xs$422679, NDSolve`xs$422680, NDSolve`xs$422681,NDSolve`xs$422682, NDSolve`xs$422683, NDSolve`xs$422684, etc. <<951>>} `` cannot be transposed.

Comment: Perhaps, the option `StepMonitor` would be helpful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Does look like it could be useful option. Not quite sure how to implement it into the `NDSolveValue`?

Comment: I have not used `StepMonitor`, so I cannot offer practical advice.  If you search Mathematica.Stackexchange and also the web with Google, you will find several examples and a few references.  When you solve this problem, please be sure to provide it as an answer to your question.  Many others may benefit.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Using your comment as inspiration, if I add a `Sow` tag to the finite difference scheme, and then a `Reap` tag around `NDSolveValue`. Then `sol[[2,1,1,1]]` returns the first equation from the scheme. It seems that $Q$ is 0 in this case, and continues to be. This would explain why nothing moves. So there's clearly a problem with my pure function syntax for Q as it should be passing 0.26 in the first equation. The syntax works for $h_0$ case so I believe the pattern matching bit is fine. It's just how to pass each successive $h$ into the $Q$ calculation.

Comment: "where $ϕ$ and $ψ$ are the angles from the base of the annulus to the middle of the right and left flat sections", then I think your definition for `Q` in the code is wrong, notice e.g. `h0[[1 ;; 500]]` isn't just formed by points on the flat section. Also, as shown in the .gif, when the section begins to move, it's no longer flat, how will you decide _the middle_ in this case?

Comment: @xzczd I use the pattern matching to only include points that are away from the sides of the annulus. So I am selecting the median position of the points not on the walls. Ie. The median position in the flat interface. I get that it won't be exactly the middle of the interface as it moves, but since the interface moves fairly uniformly it will be sufficiently approximately correct.

Comment: @xzczd That was written on mobile, so perhaps I did not explain myself so well. `h0[[1 ;; 500]]` only selects points in the left hand side of the annulus, which indeed includes points not in the flat section. However `x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999` means that the points on the inner and outer walls are excluded. Meaning we only have points from the flat section left. Again, as I stated before, this maybe only approximate as `h` moves (I could perhaps reduce tolerance to `1.01 <  x < 1.99`) but it will be close enough for my purposes.

Comment: Oh, I should have read your code more carefully, then I think I know what's wrong with your code. In short, your selection won't work, because you chose the explicit definition for `h` (which is suggested by me in the last post). Just evaluate the equation outside of `NDSolve` and you'll understand what I mean. Maybe I can write an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @xzczd I think I understand what you mean. I am asking Mma to evaluate 'h' before it has? That's what motivated me to try including 'Q[n]' in the finite difference scheme and then solve it coupled with the definition of 'Q'. That is what gave me the strange transpose error. An answer would be extremely appreciated as always.

Comment: @xzczd I've been playing around with evaluating `h` outside code, but can't seem to make any progress?

Comment: Sorry, still a little busy at the moment so can't write an answer. You should notice that `NDSolveValue` doesn't have the attribute `HoldAll` i.e. the equations inside it will be evaluate before they're sent into `NDSolveValue` so your 2 approaches won't work for the same reason. I haven't looked into the problem yet but believe the approach suggested by Michael E2 in your former approach will be easier for adapting because his `dh2` is a blackbox that won't evaluate before `h` becomes a list of number.

Comment: @xzczd Hmmm, when I try to adapt Michael E2's solution I get errors about `Compile`. 

"Part specification \
Cos[Median[Position[$h[[1;;500]],x_/;1.001<x<1.999]]\ \
Compile`$25][[1]] cannot be compiled since the argument is not a \
tensor of sufficient rank. Evaluation will use the uncompiled \
function"

I'm not really sure what compile does in this case, and what is the correct way to use it with my method of selecting the middle of the interface.

Comment: OK, now you fell into another pitfall… `Compile` isn't an easy function, you may want to read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871). If you feel `Compile` too hard and speed isn't that important for you, just use a `Function` instead of the `Compile`. (You can simply take `Compile` as something that creates fast numeric function.)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I think that the meta-problem here is that MMA doesn't allow vector-valued functions in `NDSolve` (and related solvers). Given this restriction,</strike> I couldn't figure out how to define a real-valued function $Q(h(\theta,t))$ that would incorporate into `NDSolve` with a vector set of equations $h(\theta_i,t)$, where $\theta_i\in\{x\times\pi/1000|{-1000}\leq x \leq 0\wedge x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. (Does that sound right? I think it does.)

Instead, I used `WhenEvent` inside `NDSolveValue` to discretely update $Q$ as $Q(\theta_i,h(\theta_i,t))$ for the set of equations $h(\theta_i,t)$ at each time point $t=t_i\in\{x\times0.2|0\leq x \leq 100\wedge x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

```
n = 1001;
dθ = π/(n - 1);
θ = Table[θ, {θ, -π, 0, dθ}];
functionList[h_, θ_List, t_: 0] := Table[h[s][t], {s, θ}];
h0 = N@Table[
Piecewise[{
  {1.999, -π < θ < -((7 π)/8)},
  {(2 Sin[-((6 π)/7)])/
   Sin[θ], -((6 π)/
     7) < θ < -2.0909003694838066`},
  {1.001, -2.26998149133592` < θ < -0.6662394324925154`},
  {(2 Sin[-(π/10)])/
   Sin[θ], -0.6662394324925154` < θ < -(π/10)},
  {1.999, -(π/8) < θ < 0}
  }, 1.999], {θ, θ}];
dh[h_, θ_List, t_: 0, Q_: 0.005] := 
    Module[{hθt = functionList[h, θ, t], d1, d2},
        d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/dθ, Join[{2}, hθt, {2}]]; 
        d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/dθ^2, Join[{2}, hθt, {2}]];
        (-2 + hθt) (-1 + hθt) (-18 Q d1 + (-2 + hθt)
            (-1 + hθt) (4 + hθt (-15 + 8 hθt))
            Cos[θ] d1 + (-2 + hθt) (-1 + hθt)
            ((-9 + 6 hθt) d1^2 - (2 - 3 hθt + hθt^2)
            (hθt - d2)) Sin[θ])
    ]
```

I defined the center-finding function as in the OP, but to return polar coordinates instead of just angles. Then I defined a helper function to find the interface center points for a given $h(\theta_i,t_i)$. Finally I defined $Q(\theta_i,h(\theta_i,t_i))$ and a polymorphic shortcut to work on interface data lists.

```
interfaceCenters[θ_List, hθt_List] := {
    {π/2 -dθ First@Median[#], Extract[hθt, Round[Median[#], 1]]} &@
        Position[hθt[[1 ;; 500]], x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999],
    {dθ First@Median[#], Extract[hθt, Round[Median[#], 1] + 500]} &@
        Position[hθt[[501 ;; 1001]], x_ /; 1.001 < x < 1.999]
};
Q[θ_List, hθt_List] := With[
    {iCs = interfaceCenters[θ, hθt]},
    N@Cos[iCs[[1, 1]]] - N@Cos[iCs[[2, 1]]]
];
Q[iC_List] := N@Cos[#[[1, 1]]] - Cos[#[[2, 1]]] &@iC;
Q0 = Q[\[Theta], h0];
```

Then the simulation and data generation:

```
Clear[h];
sol = NDSolveValue[{
    D[functionList[h, θ, t], t] == dh[h, θ, t,Q0],
    functionList[h, θ, 0] == h0,
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, 0.2] == 0, With[
        {q = Q[θ, functionList[h, θ, t]]},
        dh[h, θ, t,_Real] -> dh[h, θ, t, q]];
    ]
}, Head /@ functionList[h, θ, t], {t, 0, 20}];
valh = Transpose[#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ sol];
ti = Flatten@sol[[1]]["Grid"];
hSol = ListInterpolation[valh, {ti, θ}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

times = Table[ti, {ti, 0, 20, 0.2}];
interfaceData = Table[hSol @@ {ti, θ}, {ti, times}];
iCs = Table[interfaceCenters[θ, i], {i, interfaceData}];
Qs = Q /@ iCs;
```

And the animation:

```
ListAnimate@(animation = Table[
    Show[
        ListPolarPlot[Transpose[{θ, interfaceData[[i]]}],
            PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
            ImageSize -> Large,
            PlotStyle -> Black, Joined -> True, 
            Epilog -> {Text["Q = " <> ToString[Qs[[i]]], {0.1, 0.1}, {-1, -1}]}
        ],
        RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
            PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1], AspectRatio -> 1
        ],
        ListPolarPlot[{{3 π/2, 0} + {-1, 1} iCs[[i, 1]], {3 π/2, 0} + iCs[[i, 2]]},
            PlotStyle -> {{Blue, PointSize -> Large}}
        ],
        ListPolarPlot[
            Table[{{0, 0}, {{π, 0} + iCs[[i, 1]], {3 π/2, 0} + iCs[[i, 2]]}[[j]]},
                {j, Length[iCs[[i]]]}
            ],
            PlotStyle -> {{Black, Dashed}}, Joined -> True
        ]
    ], {i, Length[times]}])
Export["C:\\Users\\jdbishop\\Desktop\\test.gif", animation]
```

[image]

### Update

I think `WhenEvent` works basically like it is supposed to, and therefore constitutes a solution that is technically correct, it's just that using it to update $Q$ every means that the simulation misses the case when $Q=0$ and therefore the dynamics reach equilibrium. I've edited my answer a final time to correct the `WhenEvent` code to correct the pattern matching failure pointed out by @xzczd. However, you can see the failure to catch $Q=0$ in the animation above. So I see @xzczd's answer and think that updating $Q$ discretely is never going to be a satisfactory answer when @xzczd has shown how to update it continuously while generating the numerical solution. So that's it from me, I think, but I've learned a lot working on this problem with everyone else.

Comment: Is there a reason you changed the initial condition `h0` to have the points on the outer and inner walls exactly 1 and 2? They need to be 1.001 and 1.999 respectively or else the PDE will be equal to 0 on the outer and inner walls and will not move there, this gives an incorrect solution. When I try to change the initial condition to the previous correct one (after making the appropriate amends in `interfaceCentres` I get errors about `Part{2,4}` not existing.

Comment: Also, if I take the simulation further to $t = 60$ say, the centers of the interface clearly swap "heights", ie. the flat section on the right moves below the flat section on the right. This must mean that $\psi = \phi$ at some point, which in turn must mean $Q = 0$. This is missed by your code as $Q \neq 0$, indeed it does not even go negative as the interfaces are swapped.

Comment: I'm still massively confused about why changing the initial condition back to my original one is giving errors. I amend `h0` to be my original one, and then amend `N@SplitBy[
   Transpose[{h\[Theta]t, \[Theta]}], #[[1]] != 1.999 && #[[1]] != 
      1.001 &][[{2, 4}]]`

This amend returns the same as your code, which it should do as it throws away the inner/outer pieces and just keeps the flat bits. 

So given these amends that return the same code as yours, I have no idea why the simulation section is throwing up `Part{2,4}` does not exist errors.

Comment: @ojlm Sorry! I wasn't sure that the pattern matching approach was working that great, so I used a different approach that clearly turned out to be a rather fragile one. I've edited my answer to incorporate your center-finding function instead, which actually seems to be way faster anyway! The code ins't as general as it was before, but I think it's implemented correctly, now (at least I hope so). The remaining confusion on my side of things is why does the center of the right interface jump so quickly at $t = 0.2 s$? It doesn't seem like it's finding the correct center position...

Comment: The centre of the right interface can be stopped from jumping so quickly if we lower the tolerance: `x_ /; 1.1 < x < 1.9`. What I am more concerned about is that the interfaces clearly reach the same "heights" yet $Q \neq 0$. We have $Q = \sin \psi - \sin \phi$, so if we were capturing the angles correctly, when the heights are the same size, the angles are (approximately) the same and we should see $Q \sim 0$. However, I am seeing huge $Q$ of 0.5 never going anywhere near 0?

Comment: Also, what motivates your choice of $Q = 0.005$ in the definition of `dh[h_, \[Theta]_List, t_: 0, Q_: 0.005]` ? Thanks for all your help btw!

Comment: Good call re: using different tolerances in your pattern-matching code. $Q=0.005$ is taken from the very first block of code you posted. I'm looking more carefully at the Q calculations now....

Comment: OK, so I think maybe the angle calculations were incorrect. The function `interfaceCenters` was measuring $\psi$ from $\pi$ rather than $3\pi/2$. I made the changes in my answer and the attached *.gif to reflect the correct calculations.

Comment: Ah! The choice of $Q = 0.005$ was only to illustrate how the code worked for $Q$ being a constant. I went on to say that $Q$ should be calculated from the $Q = \sin \psi - \sin \phi$ condition instead. There should be no $Q$ constant, only the varying $Q$ in the final code. Is it enough just to remove the definition of $Q$ from `dh` ? In effect what should happen is Q tends to 0 as time moves on. It should not go beyond 0 really.

Comment: @ojlm I'm sorry, but I'm afraid the `WhenEvent` doesn't have any effect on the solution. Just take away the `WhenEvent` and solve again and `Show` both solutions on the same picture. It's not surprising, because even if the replacement inside `WhenEvent` really works at the first `Mod[t, 0.2]` (BTW `WhenEvent` is a wild beast, just search around this site), it won't work in the next place, because the `dh[h, θ, t]` has already become `dh[h, θ, t, q]` so it no longer matches the rule.

Comment: But "[**`NDSolve` can solve vector equations**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39137/finding-a-3d-curve-from-torsion-and-curvature-with-ndsolve/39142#comment117193_39157)"!

Comment: I think I fixed the pattern matching problem in my `WhenEvent` code, but the new simulation shows that updating $Q$ every 0.2 s is too coarse. The dynamics don't reach equilibrium because $Q$ never actually has the value 0. $Q$ really needs to be updated continuously during generation of the numerical solution. So aside from everything else, that's a reason to drop my approach and adopt the one supported by the work of @xzczd and @MichaelE2. I'd comment on @xzczd's answer, but I'm new to the site and don't have the reputation...

Answer (score 2):

OK, finally find some time to write the answer. First I'd like to point out why your 2 approaches failed. As mentioned in the comment above, they failed for the same reason: `NDSolve` doesn't have `Hold*` attribute, the `Position` in your code evaluates **before** the equation is sent into `NDSolve`. For more information you may have a look at [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97006/1871) about essentially the same problem.

Then I'd like to point out that your definition for $\psi$ in the code is wrong, there should be a `Pi/2 -` in the first `Cos[…]`.

Finally the following is my solution. It's based on [Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120501/1871) in your previous question:

```
ClearAll[dh2, s, h];

n = 201;
s = N@Array[# &, n, {- π, 0}];
ds = Pi/(n - 1);
dhC = With[{s = s, findmid = Last@Median@Select[#, 1.001 < #[[1]] < 1.999 &] &}, 
   Compile[{{h, _Real, 1}, {d1, _Real, 1}, {d2, _Real, 1}},
    Module[{halfl = Floor[Length@h/2], Q}, 
     Q = Cos[Pi/2 + findmid[{h, s}\[Transpose][[;; halfl]]]] - 
       Cos[-Pi/2 - findmid[{h, s}\[Transpose][[halfl + 1 ;; -1]]]];
     (-2 + h) (-1 + 
        h) (-18 Q d1 + (-2 + h) (-1 + h) (4 + h (-15 + 8 h)) Cos[
          s] d1 + (-2 + h) (-1 + h) ((-9 + 6 h) d1^2 - (2 - 3 h + h^2) (h - d2)) Sin[
          s])](*, CompilationTarget -> C*)]];

With[{(*compute derivatives and Sin[s],Cos[s] just once*)
   d1FN = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, s, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2], 
   d2FN = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, s, "DifferenceOrder" -> 1]}, 
  dh2[h_List] := With[{d1 = d1FN@h, d2 = d2FN@h}, dhC[h, d1, d2]]];

h0 = Table[Piecewise[{{1.999, -Pi < θ < -7 Pi/8}, 
             {(2 Sin[-6 Pi/7])/Sin[θ], -6 Pi/7 < θ < -2.0909003694838066`},
             {1.001, -2.26998149133592` < θ < -0.6662394324925154`}, 
             {(2 Sin[-(Pi/10)])/Sin[θ], -0.6662394324925154` < θ < -(Pi/10)}, 
             {1.999, -(Pi/8) < θ < 0}}, 1.999], 
       {θ, -1. Pi, 0., ds}];

{sol2} = h /. NDSolve[{h'[t] == dh2[h[t]], h[0] == h0}, 
                      h, {t, 0, 8.43}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming

valh = sol2["ValuesOnGrid"];
ti = Flatten@sol2["Grid"];
newsol = ListInterpolation[valh, {ti, s}]

pic = RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1]];

(*ListAnimate@*)Export["a.gif", 
 Table[Show[PolarPlot[newsol[t, θ], {θ, -Pi, 0}, PlotRange -> 2, 
    PlotStyle -> Black], pic], {t, 0, 8.4, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

I modified the end time to `8.43` because when the calculation got stuck at this point, I'm not sure about the reason, but relatively confident about the coding, perhaps it's the nature of the model?

---

**Update**

OP asked if it's possible to monitor the variation of `Q`, the answer is of course yes. We just need to add a `Sow@Q` in `dhC`:

```
dhC = With[{s = s, findmid = Last@Median@Select[#, 1.001 < #[[1]] < 1.999 &] &}, 
   Compile[{{h, _Real, 1}, {d1, _Real, 1}, {d2, _Real, 1}}, 
    Module[{halfl = Floor[Length@h/2], Q}, 
     Q = Cos[Pi/2 + findmid[{h, s}\[Transpose][[;; halfl]]]] - 
       Cos[-Pi/2 - findmid[{h, s}\[Transpose][[halfl + 1 ;; -1]]]];

     Sow@Q;

     (-2 + h) (-1 + 
        h) (-18 Q d1 + (-2 + h) (-1 + h) (4 + h (-15 + 8 h)) Cos[
          s] d1 + (-2 + h) (-1 + h) ((-9 + 6 h) d1^2 - (2 - 3 h + h^2) (h - d2)) Sin[
          s])](*,CompilationTarget\[Rule]C*)]];
```

*Notice `Sow` is actually not compilable, but usually it won't slow down `CompiledFunction` that much. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15908/1871)'s another example.*

Then add a `Reap` outside of `NDSolve`:

```
{{sol2}, {Qlst}} = 
   Reap[h /. NDSolve[{h'[t] == dh2[h[t]], h[0] == h0}, h, {t, 0, 8.43}, 
      MaxSteps -> Infinity]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

OK, let's check the variation of `Q`:

```
ListPlot[Qlst, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It goes to `0`, as you expected.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand why the interface moves so much. The $Q$ should tend to 0 and then stay there. Almost like John Bishop's solution does. You can see how the $Q$ varies and goes to 0 - his goes beyond 0 which is another sauce of confusion for me. Is it possible to list the $Q$ at each time step in your solution? `StepMontior` I guess in `NDSolveValue` ?

Comment: @ojlm As mentioned in the comment under Bishop's answer, I think his `WhenEvent` doesn't work. As to the monitoring of `Q`, the answer is of course yes. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your update. It's great that we can see that $Q$ goes to 0, but it goes to 0 when clearly the angles are not equal? Given the definition, $Q = 0$ is when $\sin \psi = \sin \phi$. However, it's clear to me from the animation that when $Q = 0$ we have $\phi \neq \psi$.

Comment: @ojlm It's not surprising to me, because your algorithm for selecting $ψ$ and $ϕ$ is rather coarse, it takes the `Median` of points between `1.001<h<1.999`, which involves a lot of undesired points. (See those points which are quite close to the wall but clearly in the range of `1.001<h<1.999`?) I believe using a better standard e.g. `1.4<h<1.6` will result in a better result, but with this standard the calculation will become so memory-consuming that my laptop can't bear it for a long enough time...