# NDSolve with Events that reevaluate with different Discrete Variables

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, scoping, event-detection

I have the following problem:

I have a set of ODEs and some discrete variables which I can solve successfully. Now I want mathematica to check at every $0.1 \,t$ time step, wether it would increase the function $url' [t]$ to decrease the variable $\eta[t]$ and do so, if that's the case.

So I constructed the following

```
WhenEvent[Mod[t,0.1],If[url'[t] > With[{eta[t] -> 0.9 eta[t]}, url'[t]],
eta[t] -> 0.9 eta[t]]
```

However I get the error

```
"Variable NDSolve`SetState[eta[t],0.9 eta[t]] in local 
variable specification \{NDSolve`SetState[eta[t],0.9 eta[t]} requires a value."
```

From what I understand, the braces somehow inhibit the SetState and following reevaluation of the function.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Since `url'[t]` is treated as a variable, not as a function depending on `eta[t]`, you might have to write the formula instead of `With[..]` (which has incorrect syntax in any case). Also, I can't decipher the error with the information given. I can see what went wrong, but I can't tell why or how to fix it without code that reproduces it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you for your answer!
I have found one example of adapting parameters, but I'm afraid, I don't understand it.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/122017/updating-a-parameter-each-time-step-within-a-finite-difference-scheme

From what I understand now, the problem is the sequence of evaluation steps does not allow to evaluate the functions twice at that step.

Comment: "...does not allow to evaluate the functions twice at that step": Yes, I think that is right. That's what I meant by `url'[t]` is treated as a variable.  The value is computed once during a step and that value is used throughout the event processing.

Comment: do you know, wether there is a way, to change it? Basically alter the Solver?
Best regards

Comment: I don't know of any way to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept. Problems with code usually require the code for the problem to be analyzed, so while it accomplishes what is described, I don't know if it can be adapted to the OP's case.

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - x[t]^3, y'[t] == x[t] - y[t]^3, 
    x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}];
xp[x_, y_, e_] := -y - e x^3; (* RHS for x'[t] *)
{sol2} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == xp[x[t], y[t], eta[t]], 
    y'[t] == x[t] - y[t]^3,
    x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, eta[0] == 1,
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, 0.1], 
     If[xp[x[t], y[t], eta[t]] > xp[x[t], y[t], 0.9 eta[t]], 
      eta[t] -> 0.9 eta[t]]]},
   {x, y, eta}, {t, 0, 20}, DiscreteVariables -> {eta}];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. {sol, sol2} // Evaluate, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[eta[t] /. sol2, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very!
I'll have a look into it immediately