# Recursive function which uses Which

Tags: function-construction, recursion

I'm working on [project euler 9](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9) and I've solved it various ways. I'm using these problems to learn functional programing techniques.  I'm now attempting to mimic my friend Chris recursive elixir solution:

```
defmodule PythagoreanTriplet do
  def find_triplet(a \\ 1, b \\ 2) do
    c = :math.pow(a, 2) + :math.pow(b, 2) |> :math.sqrt
    cond do
      a + b + c == 1000.0 -> IO.puts "#{a} * #{b} * #{c} = #{a * b * c}"
      b < 500 -> find_triplet(a, b + 1)
      a < 500 -> find_triplet(a + 1, a + 2)
      true -> IO.puts "I don't know"
    end
  end
end

PythagoreanTriplet.find_triplet
```

Here is my attempt in Mathematica:

```
Clear[findTriple]
findTriple[a0_, b0_] := findTriple[a0, b0] =
  Module[
   {a = a0, b = b0, c = Sqrt[a0^2 + b0^2]},
   Which[a + b + c == 1000, Print[a*b*c],
    b < 500, findTriple[a, b + 1],
    a < 500, findTriple[a + 1, a + 2]
    ]
   ]
findTriple[1, 2]
```

I'm getting `$RecursionLimit: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation` errors.  I've read through related posts and I'm over my head.  Thank you.

Comment: No recursion needed: `FindInstance[a^2 + b^2 == c^2 ∧ a + b + c == 1000 ∧ a < b < c ∧ {a, b, c} ∈ Integers ∧ {a, b, c} > 0, {a, b, c}, 1]`

Comment: Thanks =)  I'm using this problem as a way to understand recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done with a recursive function that uses `Which`, but that function won't be able to compute the answer for large values of the sum. Here is how such a recursive function is properly written.

```
Clear[findTriple]
findTriple[sum_, a_: 1, b_: 2] :=
  Block[{$RecursionLimit = 100000, c = Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]},
    Which[
      a + b + c == sum, {a, b, c},
      b <= sum/2, findTriple[sum, a, b + 1],
      a <= sum/2, findTriple[sum, a + 1, a + 2],
      True, Failed[a, b, c]]]
```

With this definition

```
findTriple[420]
```

> `{28, 195, 197}`

works on my computer, but

```
findTriple[421]
```

doesn't complete because it runs out of memory.

So does this mean Mathematica can't solve the problem recursively. No, it doesn't. It means we must be more careful about how we write the recursion; we must make it tail-recursive, like so:

```
Clear[helper]
helper[sum_, a_, b_] /; a + b + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] == sum := {a, b, Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]}
helper[sum_, a_, b_] /; b <= sum/2 := helper[sum, a, b + 1]
helper[sum_, a_, b_] /; a <= sum/2 := helper[sum, a + 1, a + 2]
helper[_, a_, b_] := Failed[a, b, Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]

Clear[findTriple]
findTriple[sum_] :=
  Block[{$IterationLimit = 100000}, helper[sum, 1, 2]]

findTriple[1000]
```

> `{200, 375, 425}`

Since all the real work is done when the righthand side of `helper` is evaluated, this version is both fast and uses little memory.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the help I needed to better understand how recursion works here.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid the Recursion error you can instead use `NestWhile`, which effectively implement the same logic in a more efficient manner:

```
NestWhile[
 Which[
   #[[2]] < 500, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + 1},
   #[[1]] < 500, {#[[1]] + 1, #[[1]] + 2},
   True, Abort[]
   ] &,
 {1, 2},
 (Total@# + Norm@# != 1000) &
 ]
(* Out[1]= {200, 375} *)
```

An easy way to solve the problem without using recursion is to instead just use `SelectFirst`, as in:

```
SelectFirst[
 Subsets[Range@500, {2}],
 Norm@# + Total@# == 1000 &
 ]
```

Also, for a *much* faster solution, you should have a look at [Mr.Wizard's function to generate Pythagorean triples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15904/27539).
Using his function and `SelectFirst`, the solution of the problem is obtained immediately with:

```
SelectFirst[
 genPTunder[500],
 Total@# == 1000 &
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I love the use of the pure functions.  That's on my list to mess with also.