# Delete elements from a list really fast

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I have this bit of code that works, but it's very slow when there are 600k elements in the list:

```
mytbl = {};
ParallelDo{
   If[Flatten[left][[i]] == 1 || Flatten[left[[i]]==0,
     mytbl = AppendTo[mytbl, Flatten[left][[i]]];
   ];,
   {i, Length[Flatten[left]]}
];
```

Is there a significantly faster way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at `Cases`

Comment: `Append` and `AppendTo` are notoriously slow because lists are array-like and have to be copied to increase their size.

Comment: Wow Cases is very fast - thanks!

Comment: I don't think that operating on a single structure from several parallel processes as you do here with `ParallelDo` is efficient or save. Compare `i = {};
ParallelDo[i = {i, j}, {j, 1, 100}];i` With the result you get for a standard `Do`.

Comment: Levi, your code is not executable (invalid syntax).  Please correct it.

Comment: A very belated welcome to Mathematica.SE! :) I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 16):

Some possibilities with their timings:

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 600000];

Cases[list, 0 | 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.065004, Null}

```
Select[list, # == 0 || # == 1 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.865050, Null}

```
DeleteCases[list, Except[0 | 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.242014, Null}

```
Pick[list, # == 0 || # == 1 & /@ list]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.922053, Null}

```
 Pick[list, list, 0 | 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.189011, Null}

```
Replace[list, {0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, _ :> Sequence[]}, {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.213012, Null}

```
Replace[list, a_ :> Sequence[] /; Not[a == 0 || a == 1], {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.652095, Null}

```
Replace[list, Except[0 | 1] :> Sequence[] , {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.238014, Null}

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Oops; forgot to copy that. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You may gain some additional speed by compiling the expression at hand, in the example given by [Sjoerd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19125/21) it is about one order of magnitude when compiled to C.

```
cf = Compile[{{in, _Integer, 1}},
   Block[{newList = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]]},
    Do[
     If[in[[i]] == 0 || in[[i]] == 1, 
      Internal`StuffBag[newList, in[[i]]];]
     , {i, Length[in]}];
    Internal`BagPart[newList, All]
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

list = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 600000];
(res1 = Cases[list, 0 | 1];) // AbsoluteTiming
(res2 = cf[list];) // AbsoluteTiming
res1 === res2

(*
{0.070894, Null}
{0.007514, Null}
res1 === res2
*)
```

An explanation of the compiled code can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/21).

Answer (score 4):

You can gain almost an order of magnitude improvement using [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick) with [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep):

```
list = RandomInteger[{0,10}, 10^6];

r1 = Cases[list, 0|1]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Pick[list, UnitStep[list-2], 0]; //RepeatedTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.060, Null}
>
> {0.0078, Null}
>
> True

Comment: +1. I'm surprised no one had posted a `UnitStep` solution -- it's been used so many times elsewhere on the site!  Note it's not clear whether the integers are nonnegative in the OP, but `r2 = Pick[list, UnitStep[list] UnitStep[1 - list], 1]` is still quite a bit faster.

Comment: And this works on reals, too: `Pick[list, Unitize[list] Unitize[list - 1], 0]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In addition to UnitStep, there are variations with Ramp, Clip, Sign, Unitize etc that could be used. It's not always clear which version is optimal.

Comment: @CarlWoll thanks for mentioning answer with UnitStep ! when i write my code now I try to see if any of these functions can be used

Answer (score 1):

`Pick` using `Boole` to construct the selector array is *almost* as good as `Cases`:

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 600000];
casesLst = Cases[list, 0 | 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.057006, Null} *)
pickBooleLst = Pick[list, Boole[# == 0 || # == 1] & /@ list, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.063006, Null} *)
pickLst1 = Pick[list, list, 0 | 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.142014, Null} *)
pickLst2 = Pick[list, # == 0 || # == 1 & /@ list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.866087, Null} *)
casesLst == pickBooleLst
(*  True *)
```