# Listable compiled function using Map

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

I'm trying to minimize the computation time of problem which is too long to post. I use `compile`in order to gain some speed. To increase speed I would like to use the options `Parallelization -> True`and `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` among others. The problem is now that some built-in functions I use, such as `Map`, do not have the attribute `Listable`. Thus, it seems that my code produces an error once the input is e.g. a list instead of a real number. To gain some insights I post some toy-code.

```
toy=Compile[{{h1,_Real},{list,_Real,1}},
leg=Length[list];
Map[Total[{list[[#]]}]/h1&, Range[leg]],
 CompilationTarget->"C",
 Parallelization->True,
 RuntimeAttributes->{Listable},
 RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

What this code does is it divides each element of `list` by `h1`. Please notice that this code does not have any meaning but to show the problem of using a non-listable function within a compile function. Now, let `h1` be some real and `list` be some random list. Then,

```
 h1=0.1; list=RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 100]; toy[h1, list]
```

works just fine. However, if one sets

```
h1={0.1,0.2}; toy[h1, list]
```

results in an error.

My question is whether one of you knows a simple way to make this compiled function listable.

One may use e.g. a `Do`-loop to get the result, but this is too slow. Thanks in advance I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

I hope your `toy` function really is just a toy-function because neither the `Map` nor the *pure function* is required to calculate what you want.

The problem with your code is that you did not localize `leg`! If you do so, the code runs fine.

```
toy = Compile[{{h1, _Real}, {list, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{leg = Length[list]},
    Map[Total[{list[[#]]}]/h1 &, Range[leg]]
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

If you don't localize all variables, *Mathematica* assumes you mean the global symbol `leg` and calls the kernel from within the compiled function to evaluate it. You should therefore always check your compiled code with:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[toy]
```

and ensure, that there are no (unwanted) `MainEvaluate[..]` calls in it.

Comment: There is a `led` blinking in the text where someone's `leg` should be.

Comment: @halirutan: Thanks for your help. Usually, I do indeed localize all variables but for some reason I get an error once I localize the relevant variable in the "non-toy" code. The error reads: "nontensor object generated". I don't know why this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I found an answer to my question which I would like to share. I seems very basic and has to do with ragged lists that I created. These lists look e.g. like `{{0,1},{1,2,3}}`. `Compile`is not able to handle these lists. I tried to avoid this using `Flatten`but this does not work. Why did I create ragged lists in the first place? To save time. I was aware that I could achieve the same results using a loop and AppendTo`, however, this function is very slow.

I found this very nice thread [Internal`Bag inside Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile). It is basically an alternative to `AppendTo` but much much faster. Now, `Compile`seems more intuitive then before.