# Better code to find Narcissistic number

Tags: programming, functional-style, meta-programming

My code finding [Narcissistic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) is not that slow, but it's not in functional style and lacks flexibility: if $n \neq 7$, I have to rewrite my code. Could you give some good advice?

```
nar = Compile[{$},
   Do[
    With[{
       n = 1000000 a + 100000 b + 10000 c + 1000 d + 100 e + 10 f + g,
       n2 = a^7 + b^7 + c^7 + d^7 + e^7 + f^7 + g^7},
      If[n == n2, Sow@n];
      ],
     {a, 9}, {b, 0, 9}, {c, 0, 9}, {d, 0, 9}, {e, 0, 9}, {f, 0, 9}, {g, 0, 9}],
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

Reap[nar@0][[2, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.398023, {1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315}}*)
```

Comment: 4679307774 is the sole such number of 10 digits. I'd not refer to the code implicated in this case as elegant, so much as disappointing (was hoping it could handle such a computation in less than the 15 hours it took).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a functional approach:

```
Narciss[x_] :=  With[{num = IntegerDigits[x]}, Total[num^Length[num]] == x]
```

Here is a compiled version of the above function:

```
NarcissC =  Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, 
  With[{num = IntegerDigits[x]}, Total[num^Length[num]] == x], 
  Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Now you can do something like

```
AbsoluteTiming[Position[NarcissC[Range[10000000]], True] // Flatten]
```

> {1.003214, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208,
>   9474, 54748, 92727, 93084, 548834, 1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 
>   9926315}}

to get all the *m*-Narcissistic numbers from 1 to 10000000.

For a further bump in speed as suggested by chyaong, here is `NarcissC2` (Using `Sum` instead of `Total`)

```
NarcissC2 = Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, 
   With[{num = IntegerDigits[x]}, Sum[i^Length@num, {i, num}] - x], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions-> "Speed"];
```

Now you can do:

```
Pick[#, NarcissC2[#], 0] &@Range[10000000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Which gives:

> {0.475276, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208,
>   9474, 54748, 92727, 93084, 548834, 1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315}}

**EDIT**

It turns out that you can get a bump using `Total` and `Pick` instead of `Position` (not as fast as `Sum`):

```
  NarcissC1 =  Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, 
    With[{num = IntegerDigits[x]}, Total[num^Length[num]] - x], Parallelization -> True, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Then

```
Pick[#, NarcissC1[#], 0] &@Range[10000000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

gives:

```
{0.626322, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208,
   9474, 54748, 92727, 93084, 548834, 1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315}}
```

Comment: Nice! However, your final timing uses `NarcissC2` whereas you only define `NarcissC`

Comment: @WalkingRandomly, I was just editing that. `NarcissC2` on my system is what I copied here as `NarcissC`

Comment: no worries. On my machine, your code takes about 2 seconds..so several times slower than the original code.  How fast did the original take on yours?  Ahh, I see why. You used `Timing` instead of `Absolute Timing`

Comment: You need to use `AbsoluteTiming` in your code for a proper comparison. Your code does more work though!  Anyway, very nice. I gave it a +1

Comment: @WalkingRandomly, you're right. Fixed it. It takes about 1 second now. so the original is about 4 to 5 times faster. But like you said, mine is doing more work. Thanks, +1 to you too.

Comment: I think `Sum[i^Length@num, {i, num}]` is faster than `Total[num^Length[num]]` in `NarcissC`:).

Comment: `NarcissC2 = 
 Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, 
  With[{num = IntegerDigits[x]}, Sum[i^Length@num, {i, num}] - x], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]; 
Pick[#, NarcissC2[#], 0] &@Range[10000000] // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @chyaong. You're right, it cuts the time about half. Do you want to post it as separate answer or should I include it and give you credit for it?

Comment: You can include it in your answer.:)

Answer (score 10):

Not an answer *per se*, but two clarifications (which are too long for the comment box):

1) The Wiki definition you have linked to for a narcissistic number is not really apt. The Wiki page is actually describing the definition for an Armstrong Number, also known as pluperfect digital invariants, or *m*-narcissistic numbers, such as:

$$407 = 4^3 + 0^3 + 7^3$$

These require the use of the power term $m$ (the 3 in this example) over and above the digits of integer $n= 407$.  By contrast, the correct and proper reference to the term 'narcissistic number' comes from the article by Madachy, J. S. (1966), *Mathematics on Vacation*, Thomas Nelson & Sons — p.163 to 175, who defines them as numbers:

"that are representable, in some way, by mathematically manipulating the digits of the numbers themselves".

What the Wiki page describes ... the Armstrong numbers ... is quite different, ... not the 'narcissistic numbers', as the page claims, but the *m*-narcissistic numbers. But that's wiki for you.

2) Finite to infinite:
The set of narcissistic numbers involve a finite search (such as the solutions above). The problem becomes rather more tricky if you allow for the use of radicals or factorials ... because the search problem is no longer finite ... rather you can have infinite nesting of square root symbols or factorial symbols.

[image]

One can get some pretty results when you allow radicals, such as say:

[image]

For more detail, please see:

http://www.tri.org.au/numQ/pwn/

or a fun little piece I did entitled:

Radical Narcissistic Numbers, *Journal of Recreational Mathematics*, 33(4), 2004-2005, 250-254.

I've been meaning to put up the mma code for this too ... this was done long before the age of multi-processors, so I think I'll have to update the code for parallel cores, which would make an enormous difference here.

Answer (score 6):

```
nar[m_] := 
  ToExpression[
   "Compile[{$},Do[With[{n=0" <> 
    StringJoin[
     Table["+1" <> Array["0" &, m - 1 - i, 1, StringJoin] <> "a" <> 
       ToString[m - 1 - i], {i, 0, m - 1}]] <> ",n2=0" <> 
    Table["+a" <> ToString[m - 1 - i] <> "^" <> ToString[m], {i, 0, 
      m - 1}] <> "},If[n\[Equal]n2,Sow@n];];,{a0" <> 
    StringJoin[Table[",0,9},{a" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, m - 1}]] <> 
    ",9}],RuntimeOptions\[Rule]\"Speed\",CompilationTarget\[Rule]\"C\"\
]"];

Reap[nar[7][0]][[2, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{1.184733, {9926315, 1741725, 9800817, 4210818}}*)
```

My computer is rather slow. @RunnyKine's code takes 0.901549 seconds on my computer.

Comment: Interesting way of code generation :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar I'm thinking the same!

Answer (score 5):

From a cold start, I would have written it like this:

```
 findNarc = Compile[{{stop, _Integer}, {pow, _Integer}},
   Do[
    If[Total[IntegerDigits[n]^pow] == n, Sow[n]]
    , {n, 1, stop}
    ]
   , RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

However, it is slower than your function (which takes 0.326 seconds on my machine)

```
Reap[findNarc[10000000, 7]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{2.900166, {Null, {{1, 1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315}}}}*)
```

I'd usually use InternalBag instead of Sow since it can be compiled whereas Sow cannot (see [Internal`Bag inside Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile) ) but Sow is called so infrequently here that I don't think that's the problem. Besides, you used it as well so both my code and your code would have been hit by the same penalty.

So, for the sake of speed, I'd be tempted to just do a very minor modification of your code to give the flexibility for choosing the Power:

```
nar = 
  Compile[{{pow, _Integer}}, 
   Do[With[{n = 
        1000000 a + 100000 b + 10000 c + 1000 d + 100 e + 10 f + g, 
       n2 = a^pow + b^pow + c^pow + d^pow + e^pow + f^pow + g^pow}, 
      If[n == n2, Sow@n];];, {a, 9}, {b, 0, 9}, {c, 0, 9}, {d, 0, 
     9}, {e, 0, 9}, {f, 0, 9}, {g, 0, 9}], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

Reap[nar[7]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.329019, {Null, {{1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315}}}}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Dynamically generated `Do` loops:)

```
cnar =
  With[{n = 7},
   With[{var = Array[Unique["x"] &, n]},
    With[{n1 = FromDigits@var, n2 = Total[var^n]},
     Compile[{Null},
        Do[If[n1 == n2, Sow@n1], ##],
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"
        ] & @@ MapAt[1 &, Thread[{var, 0, 9}], {1, 2}]
     ]
    ]
   ];

Reap[cnar@0][[2, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*
CompiledFunction[{$$}, 
 Do[If[10 (10 (10 (10 (10 (10 x3 + x4) + x5) + x6) + x7) + x8) + x9 ==
     x3^7 + x4^7 + x5^7 + x6^7 + x7^7 + x8^7 + x9^7, 
   Sow[10 (10 (10 (10 (10 (10 x3 + x4) + x5) + x6) + x7) + x8) + 
     x9]], {x3, 1, 9}, {x4, 0, 9}, {x5, 0, 9}, {x6, 0, 9}, {x7, 0, 
   9}, {x8, 0, 9}, {x9, 0, 9}], "-CompiledCode-"]

{0.358024, {1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315}}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be much faster to generate all possible integer digit sets, and then select those integer digit sets that have the require property. For instance, $135, 153, 315, 351, 513, 531$ all have the integer digits $1, 3, 5$, but the sum of the cubes of all 6 digit sets is the same, namely, $153$. The set of all possible integer digit sets for an integer length $k$ number (assuming leading 0s are acceptable) is $\binom{k+9}{k}$, which is much smaller than the set of all integers with integer length less than or equal to $k$. For instance, for $k=7$, we have:

```
10^7-1
Binomial[9+7, 7]
```

> 9999999
>
> 11440

Checking each of the integer digit sets will be much faster than checking all integers. Here is a function that carries out this idea:

```
narcisist[p_, k_] := With[
    {subs=Transpose[Transpose @ Subsets[Range[0, 8+k], {k}] - Range[0, k-1]]},

    With[
        {tdigits=Sort/@IntegerDigits[Total[subs^p,{2}],10,k]},

        Total[Pick[subs,Total[Abs[subs-tdigits],{2}],0]^p,{2}]
    ]
]
```

I extended the concept to having independent powers $p$ and integer lengths $k$. Here is the answer for the OP parameters:

```
narcisist[7, 7] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.020188, {0, 1, 9800817, 4210818, 1741725, 9926315}}

This approach can succeed for much larger integer lengths:

```
narcisist[10, 10] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.215505, {0, 1, 4679307774}}

```
narcisist[20, 20] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {112.554, {0, 1, 63105425988599693916}}

Answer (score 3):

A fast method：

```
nar[n_] := Pick[#, #~BitXor~Range[10^(n - 1), 10^n - 1], 0] &@
  Flatten[Outer[Plus, ##] & @@ Array[Range[Boole[# == 1], 9]^n &, n]]

nar /@ Range[7] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.314020, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {}, {153, 370, 371, 
>      407}, {1634, 8208, 9474}, {54748, 92727, 
>      93084}, {548834}, {1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315}}}

Answer (score 2):

This may not be efficient but it is terse:

```
narc[n_] := Module[{r, l, t},
  r = Range[n];
  t = Total@(#^Length[#]) & /@ (IntegerDigits /@ r);
  Pick[r, r - t, 0]
  ]
```

`narc[10000000]` yields:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208, 9474, \
54748, 92727, 93084, 548834, 1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315}
```

Comment: A bit faster：`Module[{r, l, t},
  r = Range[10^6];
  t = Total[With[{id = IntegerDigits@#}, id^Length@id]] & /@ r;
  Pick[r, r~BitXor~t, 0]] // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @chyaong thank you...nice