# Using compile with indexed variables

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, compile

I have the following piece of code which I made faster by using compile. I make the following definitions

```
(*The following are some preliminary definitions*)
u[z_, zb_] := z zb
v[z_, zb_] := (1 - z) (1 - zb)
k[a_][x_] := x^(a/2) Hypergeometric2F1[a/2, a/2, a, x]
gp[\[CapitalDelta]_][l_][z_, 
  zb_] := (-1)^
   l (k[\[CapitalDelta] + l][z]*k[\[CapitalDelta] - l][zb] + 
     k[\[CapitalDelta] + l][zb]*k[\[CapitalDelta] - l][z])/2^l
Fp[d_, \[CapitalDelta]_, l_][z_, 
  zb_] := (v[z, zb]^d*gp[\[CapitalDelta]][l][z, zb] - 
    u[z, zb]^d*gp[\[CapitalDelta]][l][1 - z, 1 - zb])/(u[z, zb]^d - 
    v[z, zb]^d)
z[X_, Y_] := 1/2 + X + I Y
zb[X_, Y_] := 1/2 + X - I Y

F[d_, \[CapitalDelta]_, l_][X_, Y_] := 
 Fp[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][z[X, Y], zb[X, Y]]
(*seriesF[d_,\[CapitalDelta]_,l_][x_, \
y_]:=(Series[F[d,\[CapitalDelta],l][k x,k y],{k, 0, \
6}]//Simplify//Normal)/.k->1*)
(*This function finds the m, n derivative*)
fn[d_, \[CapitalDelta]_, l_][m_, n_] := 
 Re[SeriesCoefficient[
   F[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][x, y], {x, 0, m}, {y, 0, n}]]

(*The following are the (m,n) components of the derivatives of F evaluated at x = y =0*)
(*Computing the derivatives*)
D40[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][4, 0];
D04[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][0, 4];
D20[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][2, 0];
D02[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][0, 2];
D42[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][4, 2];
D24[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][2, 4];
D22[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][2, 2];
D06[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][0, 6];
D60[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][6, 0];
```

Then I use make the following definitions using `Compile`

```
d22 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D22[b, l], {{D22[_, _], _Real}}];
d20 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D20[b, l], {{D20[_, _], _Real}}];
d02 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D02[b, l], {{D02[_, _], _Real}}];
d24 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D24[b, l], {{D24[_, _], _Real}}];
d42 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D42[b, l], {{D42[_, _], _Real}}];
d40 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D40[b, l], {{D40[_, _], _Real}}];
d04 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D04[b, l], {{D04[_, _], _Real}}];
d60 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D60[b, l], {{D60[_, _], _Real}}];
d06 = Compile[{{b, _Real}, {l, _Real}}, 
   D06[b, l], {{D06[_, _], _Real}}];
```

Next I want to define the following function called `sum` using compile so that it runs faster

```
sum = Compile[{{\[CapitalDelta], _Real}, {l, _Real}, 
 c[0, 4] d04[\[CapitalDelta], l] + c[4, 0] d40[\[CapitalDelta], l] + 
  c[2, 0] d20[\[CapitalDelta], l] + c[0 , 2] d02[\[CapitalDelta], l] +
   c[4, 2] d42[\[CapitalDelta], l] + c[2, 4] d24[\[CapitalDelta], l] +
   c[2, 2] d22[\[CapitalDelta], l] + c[0, 6] d06[\[CapitalDelta], l] +
   d60[\[CapitalDelta], l]]
```

But upon evaluating `sum[2,2]`, this gives me the error

```
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
```

Is there a way to fix this? I came across [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183912/indexed-variables-in-compile) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289247/using-indexed-variables-in-compile) post about using indexed variables in `Compile` and it seems like one cannot do it but my variables `c[i,j]` need not be indexed I can just call them `cij`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. If you really need the code to be fast, forget about 3rd argument of `Compile`. Have you read this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43128/1871 2. `Hypergeometric2F1` is in the way, it cannot be compiled: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/1871

Comment: @xzczd but it is really making the code fast. I am getting improved performance after using compile on the functions d20, etc. Thanks for sharing the articles, I have not read them.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this, but it looks like you are summing the nonzero series terms up to sixth order around $x=y=0$. Would it help to just instead look at the limit of `F` as $x \rightarrow 0$ along the curve $y= x$ ? `Limit[F[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][x, x], x -> 0]`

Comment: @xzczd ignoring 3rd argument of compile gives me a warning, should I still ignore this?