# How to evaluate a function on a list until stable?

Tags: functional-style

I need to evaluate a function `func` on a range of integers (NOT recursively, just sequentially) until the result is stable enough. I can write a not very clever step-by-step program using `While`:

```
Module[{variation,list={},j=1},

  AppendTo[list,func[1]];
  variation = Abs@First@list;

  While[variation>threshold,
    j++; AppendTo[list,func[j]]; variation = Abs[list[[j]]-list[[j-1]]];];

list    
]
```

but I would prefer using proper functional programming.

Ideally, I would like a function that I can map on a `Range[nMax]`, which stops on its own if the result has become stable (say, to within some absolute threshold) and returns the list of numbers. In this way I could also control the maximum number `nMax` of evaluations:

```
stableList[func,threshold]/@Range[nMax]
```

I suspect I have to use some clever trick (memoization?) to allow `Map` to compare previous values. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a FixedPoint function.

Comment: I don't need recursion though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible implementation of `stableList` that evaluates `fun` sequentially:

```
stableList[func_, threshold_, nMax_: Infinity] := 
  NestWhileList[{func[#], #} &[Last@# + 1] &, {func[1], 1}, 
    Abs[First@#1 - First@#2] > threshold &, 2, nMax - 1][[All, 1]]
```

Usage example:

```
fun[x_] := 1/x

stableList[fun, 0.01]
```

> `{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9, 1/10, 1/11}`

```
stableList[fun, 0.00001, 7]
```

> `{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7}`

An alternative implementation using [`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html) instead of [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html):

```
stableList2[func_, threshold_, nMax_: Infinity] := 
  FixedPointList[{func[#], #} &[Last@# + 1] &, {func[1], 1}, nMax - 1, 
    SameTest -> (Abs[First@#1 - First@#2] < threshold &)][[All, 1]]
```

And one that is based on using [`While`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/While.html?q=While), but is more efficient than yours

```
stableList3[func_, threshold_, nMax_: Infinity] := Reap[
  Module[{n = 1, difference = Infinity, newResult},
    newResult = Sow[func[n++]];
    While[n <= nMax && difference > threshold,
      difference = Abs[newResult - (newResult = Sow[func[n++]])];
    ];];][[2, 1]]
```

Comment: Overloading the `stableList` function for the case without a `nMax` will be faster than defining `nMax` as an optional argument with default value `Infinity` as checking `n <= nMax` isn't needed if there is no `nMax`.

Answer (score 8):

`FixedPointList[f, expr, n, SameTest -> g[e1,e2]]` evaluates `f[expr]` recursively for at most `n` times. It also stops if `g[e1,e2]` returns true. `e1` and `e2` being the most recent values. It is very similar to `NestWhileList`. There is also a version that returns only the last value, called `FixedPoint`.

`Map` is not meant to be used sequentially, and so you can't break out of it the way you can break out of a loop. This makes it unsuitable. You can build your own function using plain recursion like this:

```
f[e1_, e2_, e3_] := If[
  Abs[e1 - e2] > 0.001,
  f[(e1 + 2/e1)/2, e1, {(e1 + 2/e1)/2, e3}],
  Flatten@{e1, e3}
  ]

f[2.0, 10.0, {}]

(* Out: {1.41421, 1.41421, 1.41422, 1.41667, 1.5} *)
```

This particular function approximates the square root of 2.

---

**EDIT.** This is a comment on Jacob's answer that is to large to be posted as a comment. I would write his first function like this:

```
stableList[threshold_, f_] := Reap@Module[{prev, next, j},
   For[j = 1, j < 3 || Abs[next - prev] > threshold, j++,
    prev = next;
    next = Sow@f@j;
    ]
   ]
```

It is more readable in my opinion, and also equivalent

```
thres = 0.00001;
func = 1/# &;
stableList[thres, func][[2, 1]] == intermitThresDif[thres]
(* Out: True *)
```

I'm not convinced that a procedural approach is advantageous to a functional approach for this problem, especially not in Mathematica. Functionally this code could for example be implemented as

```
func2[{x_, y_}] := {1/y, y + 1}
stableList2[threshold_, f_] := First /@ NestWhileList[f, {1, 2}, Abs[First@# - First@#2] > threshold &, 2]
```

which I think is even more succinct, and equivalent

```
thres = 0.00001;
func = 1/# &;
stableList2[thres, func2] == intermitThresDif[thres]
(* True *)
```

If you use a procedural approach you should try to use `Compile`, which can indeed be much faster than a functional approach (without `Compile` it should be slower; Jacob tested and it turns out they are equally fast). [Deleted text re. `AppendTo` here]. If you compile your code you can use [`` Internal`Bag ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile) instead of `Append` and `AppendTo`. But it's better (if you intend to compile the code) to create a list equal in length to a max number of attempts and then use `Part` to update elements of that list (this is not good if you are not compiling the code.) See Jacob's answer for more information.

Comment: Hey Pickett, thanks for your response. You make some good points. For example I like how you managed to put everything in the body of the `For` loop and avoided nonsense like `variation = threshold+1`. I suppose I should have done this but I had a weird preference for `While` in cases like this. I was about to implement a better functional solution when I saw your edit and I like your use of `NestWhileList` here. I guess my procedural code should be a bit slower because I have more intermediate definitions and I suppose `NestWhileList` avoids the need to ... evaluate a bunch of `Sow`s. But...

Comment: That difference in speed should be small compared to compiled vs uncompiled code. Also my advice about `Append`(To) extends to the compiled case, I suppose I will post code to show what I mean. I guess I was silly to say programming functionally is not too efficient in cases like these. Really what I want to say is that procedural code like this is not invalid, especially because of the possibility to compile.

Comment: On my machine, your two functions in your edit are about equally fast.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom You are right, I don't know why I wrote the thing I wrote about `Append`, I wasn't thinking straight. Thanks for testing the speed of the solutions. If we take a broader perspective on things and focus not just on this particular problem, the advantage of recommending a functional style to other users is that `Map`, `Table` etc. have auto-compilation, which the procedural style doesn't. Simply put, functional programming allows for more optimizations which is why I like to use it whenever I can unless I know I will be compiling the function myself.

Comment: I think your point about auto compilation is very good and I guess this even works for `Table`, as I suppose the first argument of `Table` can only be compiled if it has no side effects, which is its functional use case. I don't fully agree with everything you say, but I guess it is largely a matter of preference for procedural vs functional programming (in MMA). I would like to dive into Haskell one day, where (auto) compilation is much more advanced, giving functionally represented solutions much more speed.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom But even the best compilers for functional languages still produce code that runs at about half the speed of procedural languages. Studies show that certain programs can be implemented ten times faster in a functional language than in a procedural language but if this is not the case for you in Mathematica then it's not going to be the case for you in Haskell; in Mathematica the situation is that functional code is often faster than procedural code, so basically if functional programming should be used anywhere it should def. be used in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is not too bad. In my opinion, the main thing to learn is not to use `Append`(To) in a loop. Here is an improved version

```
func = 1/# &;
intermitThresDif =
  Function[
   {threshold},
   Reap[
     Module[
      {variation, prev, next, j = 1},
      prev = func@1;
      Sow@prev;
      variation = threshold + 1;
      While[
       variation > threshold,
       j++;
       next = func@j;
       Sow@next;
       variation = Abs[next - prev];
       prev = next
       ]
      ]
     ][[2, 1]]
   ];
```

Note that is usually easier to convert procedural code to a to compiled function, which is an advantage over a functional approach.

**Edit**: I used to have some functional code here, but that was a bit silly

---

Here is some code that shows that even in the case where you `Compile`, using `Append` in a loop is bad. I also show an alternative, which makes use of undocumented functions, but is still "pretty standard".

```
cfu1 =
 Compile[
  {{nn, _Integer}}
  ,
  Block[{bag},
   bag = Internal`Bag@ Most@{1};
   Do[Internal`StuffBag[bag, 0], {nn}];
   Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
   ]
  ,
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ];
cfu2 =
 Compile[
  {{nn, _Integer}}
  ,
  Block[{list},
   list = Most@{0};
   Do[AppendTo[list, 0], {nn}];
   list
   ]
  ,
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ];

cfu1[10^6] // Timing // First
cfu2[10^4] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.023427
> 0.053426
> ```

Comment: I added some comments at the end of my answer in response to some of the things you wrote here.

Answer (score 2):

This example from the documentation may be instructive for approximation of $\sqrt{2}$:

```
NestWhileList[(# + 2/# )/2 &, 1, Abs[#1 - #2] > 0.001 &, 2]
```

->{1, 3/2, 17/12, 577/408, 665857/470832}