# Problem with Compile and Flatten

Tags: compile, list-manipulation

I want to get two lists within a compiled function, where `r` is an integer:

```
Insert[
  DeleteCases[
   Flatten[
    Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, r - 1}, {j, i, r - 1}], 1],{0, 0}], {0, r}, r];

Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, r - 1}, {j, 0, i - 1}], 1];
```

But `Flatten` and `Compile` don't seem to work very well together:

```
Compile[{{r, _Integer}},
    Module[{list, i = 0, j},
        list = Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, r - 1}, {j, i, r - 1}];
        Flatten[list, 1];
    ]
]
```

This yields `Compile::cplist: list should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.`. It works fine without the `Flatten` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the problem you are running in to is because `list` is a ragged array, which is not allowed.  Replace `{j,i,r-1}` with `{j,r-1}` and you get a function that compiles and runs (despite the fact that it doesn't give you the desired output).

One way to get your desired output is to create a regular array with some criterion that can be selected for removal afterwards.  Note I specifically avoid the use of *pattern* since pattern matching is not allowed in Compiled functions.

This seems to work:

```
f = Compile[{{r, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{list, i = 0, j}, 
   list = Table[{i, If[j < i, -1, j]}, {i, 0, r - 1}, {j, 0, r - 1}];
   Select[Flatten[list, 1], #[[2]] =!= -1 &]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

One obvious solution that comes to my mind, especially when I see your `DeleteCases`- and `Insert`-calls, is to use [`` Internal`Bag ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/187). This makes is somewhat easy to collect all elements of your result. Let's start with the compiled equivalent of

> `Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, r - 1}, {j, 0, i - 1}], 1];`

Inside a compiled function, you would start by creating a new *bag* for your result. Important is that I'm storing your two-dimensional tensor into a one-dimensional list. This is not a problem, because we always add a pair e.g. `{0,2}` so we know that your final result can easily be rebuilt by using `Partition[..,2]` at the end:

```
f1 = Compile[{{r, _Integer}},
  Module[{res = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]]},
   Do[Internal`StuffBag[res, {i, j}, 1], {i, r - 1}, {j, 0, i - 1}];
   Partition[Internal`BagPart[res, All], 2]
  ]
]
```

Knowing this, makes the creation of your other list easy. Just replace the  `DeleteCases` and `Insert` calls by appropriate conditional events:

```
f2 = Compile[{{r, _Integer}},
  Module[{res = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]], c = 0},
   Do[
    If[c++ == r, Internal`StuffBag[res, {0, r}, 1]];
    If[i == 0 && j == 0, Continue[]];
    Internal`StuffBag[res, {i, j}, 1], {i, 0, r - 1}, {j, i, r - 1}
    ];
   Partition[Internal`BagPart[res, All], 2]
  ]
]
```

You can use `CompilePrint` from the `` <<CompiledFunctionTools` `` package to verify that everything is properly compiled down.

Comment: I would like to know that why use ``res = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]]``, rather than ``res = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]]``. Because `Most[{0}]` is equvalent to `{}`.

Comment: +1 for using the terms "one obvious solution" and "Internal Bag" in the same sentence.  As far as I can tell, SE is the primary documentation source for the `Internal` context.  Are you aware of others?

Comment: @ShutaoTang Yes, `Most[{0}]` is equivalent to `{}`, but with this, *Mathematica* has the chance to see that I want an integer-list. This is the whole purpose. I'm not aware of any different way to make this kind of type-inference work. If you leave this out, then the created `Bag` will be of type `Real`.

Comment: @bobthechemist No, I'm not aware of any official documentation. In the linked Q&A, I gave a reference to a MathGroup message of Daniel Lichtblau. Additionally, there are some threads on SO about it, but no official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

All what you have to do is to tell `Compile` that `list` and `result` are in fact tensors.
You can do that by adding the optional arguments at the end of `Compile`: `{list,_Integer,3}` meaning that `list` is an integer tensor of rank 3, and `{result, _Integer,2}` meaning that `result` is a tensor of rank 2. `list` should go out of the module in this case.

Compile should look like:

```
f1 = Compile[{{r, _Integer}}, 
   result = Module[{i = 0, j}, 
      list = Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, r - 1}, {j, i, r - 1}];
      Flatten[list, 1]
      ]; (* End Module *)
   result (* Return result *)
   , {{list, _Integer, 3}, {result, _Integer, 2}}
]; (* End Compile *)
```

which yields:

```
{{0,0},{0,1},{0,2},{0,3},{0,4},{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{3,3},{3,4},{4,4}}
```

Comment: The real problem is that the compiled code still calls the main-evaluator basically for the complete body of your function.

Comment: @halirutan Interesting .. How can I check for that?

Comment: Load the package ``<<CompiledFunctionTools` `` and try `CompilePrint[f1]` on your function. Btw, `result` and `list` are not local variables in your compile call which makes it impossible to create a completely self-contained compiled function.

Comment: @halirutan Yes, I am aware of the non-local variables (I didn't really have time to think about how to solve this problem, as they can't be in a module and still be in Compile specs - or at least that's what I tried).
Thanks a lot for the introduction to `Internal\`Bag`, following its lead opened lots of learning opportunities for me. Thanks again :)