# Compile Select returns "Null tensor with rank > 1 encountered at instruction 24"

Tags: compile

This is the problematic part of one long function, wich should applyied many times to the list

```
func = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, Select[x, #[[1]] < -1 &]]
in = {{-2, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}};
func[in]
```

returns `{{-2., 2., 3.}}`, as desired.

But

```
in1 = {{-1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}};
func[in1]
```

shows the message

> ```
> CompiledFunction::cfnlts: Null tensor with rank > 1 encountered at instruction 24; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
> ```

Please help me to understand and solve the problem.

It is not unusual to have empty result in Select. The problem is that Mathematica will proceed with uncompiled version of the function. I want to speed up the execution

Comment: I suppose this is because compiled functions an have only one return type. It will have deduced that the type will be a list of lists but for the second input the returned value is {}, a different type.

Comment: It does return the correct result of `{}` though.  It is just slower than fully compiled code, thus it issues a warning message.  This is just a warning, not an error.  What sort of solution are you looking for?  Is this causing a performance problem in your actual application?

Comment: @Sjoerd It is true that representing empty tensors is problematic with traditional Mathematica expressions.  Generally, tensors which have a 0-dimension get messy ... had to deal with this with MATLink as MATLAB actually supports them and differentiates a 1 by 0 matrix from a 0 by 1 matrix. In Mathematica we can only have `{{}}` to represent a 1 by 0 one.  **But,** packed arrays are a little different, and it is actually possible to have an LibraryLink `MTensor` which has rank 2 yet it is empty.  If I specify the type `{Real, 2}` in LibraryLink, i.e. 2-dimensional real tensors, ...

Comment: @Sjoerd ... it will still accept *both* `{}` and `{{}}` as input, and it will create an `MTensor` which appears to be of rank 2 when queried.  I always assumed that packed arrays are stored differently and should be able to handle empty arrays when necessary (as it often is in LibraryLink code).  So I do not immediately see why the compiled function is complaining here. There is likely some other reason that I'm missing.

Comment: @Sjoerd **Interesting:** If I choose `CompilationTarget -> "C"`, which generates LibraryLink code, then the error goes away!!  This makes me wonder whether this error is a bug ... is it possible that LibraryLink can handle these empty arrays but the WVM (default compilation target) cannot?

Comment: It is nothing unusual to have empty result in Select. The problem is that Mathematica will proceed with uncompiled version of the function. I want to speed up the execution

Comment: @Szabolcs interesting, and I wouldn't really know. You're the MathLink expert ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** This seems to be a bug related to the compiled `Table` call that does work for `Table[1,0]` but gives the described error for `Table[{1},0]`.

---

Be aware that this is rather an observation than an answer. First of all, the empty array `{}` can of course be of the type `{x, _Real, 2}`. The problematic part is to tell the compiler to assume this type. This problems has been discussed elsewhere ([see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/187)).

Using this, a naive implementation of your `Select` call that works correctly can be given as

```
fNaive = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}},
  Module[{res = Most[{{0.0, 1.0, 2.0}}]},
   Do[
    If[First[elm] < -1,
     AppendTo[res, elm]
     ],
    {elm, x}
    ];
   res
   ]
  ]
```

This is neither fast nor elegant, but it shows that a working solution is possible.

Secondly, one should note that the error does not happen because of the returning type! It is simply the `Select` call itself that throws the error. When you look at the compiled instructions, you will see that the place where the error is thrown seems to be the table-call that builds the (empty) result.

Therefore, even a completely return-type-unrelated call to `Select` does throw the error. Going deeper into what's happening let's you bring down that the reason for the error to these short examples:

```
Compile[{}, Table[1, {i, 0}]][]
```

which works and

```
Compile[{}, Table[{1}, {i, 0}]][]
```

which throws the same error.

Comment: Thank you halirutan! This bug is nown since few years and not fiexed? It is mean I need an fast and correct implimentation of Select. Do you know one?

Comment: The workaround to your problem really depends on how your real application looks like. For the toy-example you have given, there clearly are some nice alternatives but I assume that this was really only an example and has nothing to do with your real requirements. If the `Select` is only a call inside a large compiled function then I would probably just ignore/silence the warning. Can you give details about your real application?