# Alternative for AppendTo

Tags: list-manipulation

as I'm well aware, using `AppendTo` for large lists isn't recommended as the function gets progressively slower with each appending done.

Lots of suggestions talk about using `Reap` and `Sow`, however the ones I found don't deal with nested lists. My question is relatively simple, how to substitute `AppendTo` with `Reap`, `Sow` as directly as possible?

Specific information regarding my problem: I would like to append data in form of

```
data = {{x}, {y}}
```

to a list, so after a few iterations, the list would look something like

```
list = {{{x1}, {y1}}, {{x2}, {y2}}, {{x3}, {y3}}}
```

My solution works for only 1 iteration, and then breaks apart because of increasing use of `Flatten`, so it's obviously a non-working solution. Of course, I'm open to other alternatives, faster than `AppendTo`.

Comment: You can sow the x and y variables to different tags, then use `Thread` or `Transpose`  to shape the separate x and y lists into the shape you want.  Look at the second argument to `Sow`

Comment: If you always generate pairs `{x,y}`, what is the problem with `Reap`/`Sow` here? If you do `list = Reap[ Do[ Sow[ {x[i], y[i]} ], {i,3} ] ][[2,1]]` you get what you want, no `Flatten`ing needed. If you generate `x` and `y` separately, see @JasonB's comment.

Comment: There is undocumented ``Internal`Bag`` described by Daniel Lichtblau in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762/590388) answer. Look also at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/280) thread for further discussion.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer your suggestion did the trick, with the few modifications :) thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the suggestions above, I could replace the following use of `AppendTo[]`:

```
For[i=1,i<10,i++,
 data = {{x},{y}};
 AppendTo[list,data];
];
```

with the use of `Reap[]` and `Sow[]`:

```
list=Reap[
 For[i=1,i<10,i++,
  data={{x},{y}};
  Sow[data];
 ];
][[2, 1]];
```

The latter produces one extra set of outer curly brackets, which you can easily remove with `Flatten[]`.

Comment: If you really need to loop, you should use `Do` instead of `For`. But probably there is a way to do what you want with `Table` instead, creating the list directly. Also, in you answer, there is no need whatsoever to include `list={};`. This is extremely rarely needed.

Comment: Noted. The data collection is a part of a larger program, hence no table :)

Comment: Seems to me that `list = Table[{{x}, {y}}, {i, 9}]` is shorter and clearer.