# Compile a program with Fold function

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I have the following small program:

```
(*Parameters*)
x0 = 4.;
g = 10.;
k = 0.5;
(*Define function*)    
fun[nTot_?IntegerQ, dt_?NumberQ] :=
 (fac = 1. - dt*k/g;
  list = Reap[Fold[Sow[fac*#] &, x0, Range[nTot]]][[2, 1]];
  list2 = ({(# - 1.)*dt, list[[#]]} & /@ Range[Length[list]]);)
(*Parameters*)
nTot = 10^7; dt = 10.^-3;
(*Computefunction*)
fun[nTot, dt]
```

which takes on my machine about 13 seconds. I want to speed it up and thought about Mathematica's `Compile` capabilities. Is there any way to `Compile` the function `fun` to C? For example [here](http://cosmosimple.blogspot.de/2013/12/some-benchmarks-of-mathematica-vs.html) it is done for a `Do` loop, but I cannot apply this to my code. Any suggestions?

**[Edit]**

Thank you again for your answer. To illustrate what I mean see the following change of my initial program:

```
f[nTot_?IntegerQ, nMem_?IntegerQ, 
  dt_?NumberQ] :=
 (fun[t_] = -163.6 E^(-2. t) + 40. E^(-1. t);
  fac1 = 1. - dt*(41.8/0.1 + 1.);
  fac2 = dt^2/0.1;
  listExp = 
   Developer`ToPackedArray[
    fun[#*dt] & /@ Range[0, nMem - 1] // Reverse];
  list = Prepend[
    Reap[Fold[Append[Rest@#, Sow[fac1*Last[#] - fac2*listExp.#]] &, 
       ConstantArray[1., nMem], Range[nTot]]][[2, 1]], 1.];
  list2 = ({(# - 1.)*dt, list[[#]]} & /@ Range[Length[list]]);)
(*Define parameters*)
nTot = 10^4; nMem = 10^5; dt = 10.^-4;
(*Compute function*)
f[nTot, nMem, dt]
```

which takes 2.3 secs on my machine. And now the (equivalent) compiled version which takes 8.4 secs on my machine:

```
fun[t_] = -163.6 E^(-2.* t) + 40. E^(-1.* t);
cfun = Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {nTot, _Integer}, {dt, _Real}, {nMem, \
_Integer}}, 
   Block[{}, x = ConstantArray[x0, nMem]; 
    fac1 = 1. - dt*(41.8/0.1 + 1.);
    fac2 = dt^2/0.1; 
    listExp = Reverse[fun[#*dt] & /@ Range[0, nMem - 1]];
    Table[{i*dt, 
      Last[x = Append[Rest@x, fac1*Last[x] - fac2*(listExp.x)]]}, {i, 
      1, nTot}]], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
clist2 = Prepend[cfun[1., 10^4, 10.^-4, 10^5], {0., 1.}];
```

Why is the compiled version now so slow? Is there a way to speed it up? Or did I do some simple mistakes? Help is highly appreciated again!

**[Edit2]:**

Ok, a small modification in the compiled version speeds it up to around 3 secs on my machine. But still it is slower compared to the solution with `Fold`:

```
fac1 = 1. - dt*(41.8/0.1 + 1.);
fac2 = dt^2/0.1;
fun[t_] = -163.6 E^(-2.* t) + 40. E^(-1.* t);
cfun = Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {nTot, _Integer}, {dt, _Real}, {nMem, \
_Integer}}, Block[{fac2 = fac2, fac1 = fac1, x, listExp},
    x = Table[x0, {i, 1, 10^5}];
    listExp = Reverse[fun[#*dt] & /@ Range[0, nMem - 1]];
    Table[{i*dt, 
      Last[x = Append[Rest@x, fac1*Last[x] - fac2*listExp.x]]}, {i, 1,
       nTot}]], {{listExp, _Real, 1}}, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
clist2 = Prepend[cfun[1, 10^4, 10^-4, 10^5], {0, 1}];
```

**[Edit3]**

Getting rid of `Append` and using `Part` instead is a little bit helpful:

```
dt = 10.^-4;
nMem = 10^5;
nTot = 10^5;
fac1 = 1. - dt*(41.8/0.1 + 1.);
fac2 = dt^2/0.1;
x0 = 1.;
x = Array[x0 &, nTot + nMem];
fun[t_] = -163.6 E^(-2.* t) + 40. E^(-1.* t);
listExp = 
  Developer`ToPackedArray[Reverse[fun[#*dt] & /@ Range[0, nMem - 1]]];
list = Table[{i*dt, 
    x[[i + nMem]] = 
     fac1*x[[i + nMem - 1]] - 
      fac2*listExp.x[[i ;; nMem + i - 1]]}, {i, 1, nTot}];
```

and a compiled version:

```
fac1 = 1. - dt*(41.8/0.1 + 1.);
fac2 = dt^2/0.1;
fun[t_] = -163.6 E^(-2.* t) + 40. E^(-1.* t);
cfun = Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {nTot, _Integer}, {dt, _Real}, {nMem, \
_Integer}}, Block[{fac2 = fac2, fac1 = fac1, x, listExp},
    x = Array[x0 &, nTot + nMem];
    listExp = Reverse[fun[#*dt] & /@ Range[0, nMem - 1]];
    Table[{i*dt, 
      x[[i + nMem]] = 
       fac1*x[[i + nMem - 1]] - 
        fac2*listExp.x[[i ;; nMem + i - 1]]}, {i, 1, 
      nTot}]], {{listExp, _Real, 1}}, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
clist2 = cfun[1, 10^5, 10^-4, 10^5];
```

**[Edit4]**

Managed to get rid of the `MainEvaluate` code by using pure function definition:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
fac1 = 1. - dt*(41.8/0.1 + 1.);
fac2 = dt^2/0.1;
fun = -163.6 E^(-2.* #) + 40. E^(-1.* #) &;
cfun = Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {nTot, _Integer}, {dt, _Real}, {nMem, \
_Integer}}, Block[{fac2 = fac2, fac1 = fac1, x, listExp},
    x = Array[x0 &, nTot + nMem];
    listExp = Reverse[fun[#*dt] & /@ Range[0, nMem - 1]];
    Table[{i*dt, 
      x[[i + nMem]] = 
       fac1*x[[i + nMem - 1]] - 
        fac2*listExp.x[[i ;; nMem + i - 1]]}, {i, 1, 
      nTot}]], {{listExp, _Real, 1}}, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "ExpressionOptimization" -> True}];
clist3 = cfun[1., 10^4, 10.^-4.5, 4*10^5];
```

Any further recommendations how to speed it up?

Comment: You want to avoid [`MainEvaluate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MainEvaluate).  See the output of ``Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]; CompilePrint@cfun``.

Comment: ``Developer`ToPackedArray`` is basically an expensive no-op inside `Compile`, because the only arrays `Compile` deals with are packed arrays.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on how to avoid `MainEvaluate` in my specific case? I inserted these commands but what does the output exactly tells me?

Comment: Ok, so `Developer`ToPackedArray` is basically a useless function within `Compile` if I get you right. But why is there an effect in my program?

Comment: Yep, `ToPackedArray` is useless inside `Compile`.  `MainEvaluate` is a call out of the compiler (actually WVM) back to the main kernel to evaluate something the compiler cannot do.  For more explanation, explore some of the Q&A in the link.

Comment: 1. For some reason `ConstantArray` is not compilable. Replace `ConstantArray[x0, nMem]` by `Table[x0,{i,1,nMem}]`. 2. Don't use `Append` in time critical loops. It involves a copy operation which is very slow. Try to build a suitable array with zeros first and then fill it with entries in the loop. If you cannot predict the length of the output, you may have a look at [``Internal`Bag``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile).

Comment: @Micheal E2: I read about pre-defining constants and use them as `a=a` in the `With[]` environment. But how can I do this with a vector like `x` or `listExp`? I don't see another way to avoid `MainEvaluate`. @Henrik Schumacher: Your first suggestion doesn't seem to have a huge effect. Your second tip is worth a try, but I think I will end up with `Part` then, and I don't know whether it is really faster to keep the very long list. I actually can predict the length of the output list since it shall be pre-defined by `nTot`.

Comment: External constants can be injected with `With` or passed as arguments.  For variables like `x`, localize them inside `Block` or `Module`  (e.g. `Block[{x, listExp}, <code>]`, as Henrik did in his answer).

Comment: Alright, there is one `MainEvaluate` left, related to `R8 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[fun][ R6]]`. How to treat this function `fun[t]`. Cannot be localized within `Block`, can it?

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: In my [Edit3] I got rid of `Append` and used indexing of a pre-defined list instead. I used `Array[]` here to create this list since according to `Compile\`CompilerFunctions[]` it is a compilable function. Still, I think one can improve the performance. If you any further idea let me please know.

Comment: @Michael E2: Managed now to get rid of the `MainEvaluate` by using a pure function definition. See my [Edit4] in the OP. However, it still is very slow unfortunately. So far your tips and the ones from Henrik Schumacher have been very helpful, so I wonder whether there is more I can do to improve the overall performance of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new task with dotting `listExp` against a moving window in `x` would have deserved a new question post.

Your problem as a very specific structure that I am going to exploit:
The list `listExp` is a sum of two lists `listExp1` and `listExp2` that are both of the form `Table[a base^i, {i,1,nMem - 1}]`. These list are dotted against a window moving along `x` resulting in numbers `sum1` and `sum2`. The main obserservation for speeding up your code is that after a moving step, `sum1` can be computed as `sum1 = (sum1 + a1 xout)/base1 + b1 xin` where `xin` is the element of `x` entering the window and `xout` is the one leaving the window. Hence, we don't have to compute the expensive dot product any more! Along with some other tweaks (replacing `Part` in read operations by `` Compile`GetElement ``, compiling into binaries via "C", and switching off some secrity checks with `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`), the code looks like this:

```
cfunDotLess = Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {nTot, _Integer}, {dt, _Real}, {nMem, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{fac2, fac1, x, listExp1, listExp2, base1, base2, sum1, sum2,
      xnew, a1, a2, b1, b2, xout, xin, j}, 
    x = Table[x0, {i, 1, nMem}];
    fac1 = 1. - dt (41.8/0.1 + 1.);
    fac2 = dt^2/0.1;
    base1 = E^(-2. dt);
    base2 = E^(-1. dt);
    a1 = -163.6 fac2;
    a2 = 40. fac2;
    sum1 = 0.;
    sum2 = 0.;
    b1 = (-a1);
    b2 = (-a2);
    Do[
     sum1 += b1 x0;
     sum2 += b2 x0;
     b1 *= base1;
     b2 *= base2;, {i, 0, nMem - 1}];
    xnew = x0;
    j = 0;
    Table[
     If[j >= nMem, j = 1, j++];
     xout = Compile`GetElement[x, j];
     xin = xnew;
     sum1 = (sum1 + a1 xout)/base1 + b1 xin;
     sum2 = (sum2 + a2 xout)/base2 + b2 xin;
     x[[j]] = xnew = Plus[fac1 xin, sum1, sum2];
     {i dt, xnew}, {i, 1, nTot}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

The following shows that `clistDotLess` is about 8000 times faster than `cfun` from Edit 4 at a cost of an acceptable loss of accuracy:

```
clistDotLess = cfunDotLess[1., 10^5, 10.^-4.5, 4.*10^5]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
clist = cfun[1., 10^5, 10.^-4.5, 4.*10^5]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[clistDotLess - clist]]

0.003614

37.028

4.63854*10^-9
```

**Edit:**  I removed some superfluous indexing into `x` and shortened `x` to be an array of length `nMem` by using indices `j` modulo `nMem`.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your effort! I wasn't aware that I should open a new topic for this one, but I will certainly do next time. I realized that in my [Edit4] I somehow lost the `Reverse` in the definition of `listExp`. I re-edited my [Edit4] to provide the correct definition as intended. I think this won't affect your answer too much, but feel free to edit it so that it is fitting to the opening post again. I will thouroughly look at your answer tomorrow, but if it is 8000 times faster than `cfun` it is exactly what I was looking and hoping for. Great!

Comment: What I do not understand is how you obtain the expression for the new `sum` after a moving step. Shouldn't it be `sum=base*sum+a*xin-a*base^(nMem+1)*xout`?

Comment: Maybe. Remember that you reverted the ordering in `listExp`. Division by `base` might become multiplication and so on. Quite likely, I also made some mistakes. I am sure you will adapt this to you problem...

Comment: Sure, I think this will just take some time. But more importantly I got the idea behind it.

Comment: That was the goal! =D

Comment: Adapted it now to my problem. Now, it is 'only' 5000 faster than the previous solution with `cfun` but that is fast enough anyways for my purposes. Again, thank you so much for your help. If I could give you more than one up vote I would certainly do.

Comment: Glad to be help!

Answer (score 7):

Your use of `Reap` and `Sow` along with `Fold` could be better formulated with `FoldList`, or even better with `NestList`. Moreover, the second sweep over `Range[Length[list]]` can be avoided at all. "Unfolding" your code and compiling it, this could look like this:

```
cfun = Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {nTot, _Integer}, {dt, _Real}, {g, _Real}, {k, _Real}},
   Block[{fac = 1. - dt*k/g, x = x0},
    Table[x *= fac; {(i - 1.)*dt, x}, {i, 1, nTot}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

clist2 = cfun[x0, nTot, dt, g, k]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.49941

Note that constructs like `Fold` and `Nest` are bound to evaluate sequentially while your result can actually obtained in parallel. A simple vectorized version of your code is this:

```
vfun[x0_?NumberQ, nTot_Integer, dt_?NumberQ, g_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ] :=
   With[{ran = N@Range[1, nTot]},
   Transpose[{(ran - 1.) dt, x0 ((1. - dt*k/g)^ran)}]
   ];
```

On my Haswell quad core, this performs like this

```
vlist2 = vfun[x0, nTot, dt, g, k]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.397826

Note that the most expensive operation in `vfun` is `Transpose`; skipping will half the cost.

Comparing the results:

```
Max[Abs[clist2 - vlist2]]
```

> 2.79776*10^-14

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations! For some reasons, `vfun` is becoming slow if `nTot=2*10^7` (25 secs) compared to `cfun` with the same `nTot` (2 secs) on my machine. What could be reason for this?

Comment: When the exponents become too large, Mathematica has to use extended precision as the results get much smaller than `$MachineEpsilon`. Extended precision calculations are much more expensive since they have to be emulated in software and since bigger data types have to be used. The compiled version does not care; it will simply return `0.` in that case.

Comment: Of course, makes totally sense. Can one avoid this behaviour? If yes, how?

Comment: Ok, `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]` should do the job.

Comment: Good point. Yeah, a thought about it in the meantime: I think Mathematica cannot switch to extended precision because `(1. - dt*k/g)` has machine precision. So, it's the error handling that slows things down. Very good!

Comment: Another observation is that skipping `Transpose` does not really half the cost. At least not after setting the `"CatchMachineUnderflow"` to `False`. For `nTot=10^9` timing is almost identical.

One further question about the vectorized code: Here, the next element only depends on the previous one. And it is easy to see that vectorization is possible.

But what about the case, where I have memory and the next element depends on a (infinite) list of previous elements. In this case vectorization is probably not possible anymore, right? Hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: Hm. I cannot confirm that. However, these things may depend quite much on the specific architecture, e.g. on  Flops/s vs. Byte/s (transposition is involves copying and thus is memory bound). My machine is quite good at Flops/s but the memory is rather old (due to the Haswell architecture I use).

Comment: In principle: whenever the next element cannot be computed without knowning the previous element, parallelization cannot be used. (That's not entirely true as there are such algorithms as Parareal). But in your case, we are able to predict the value of an arbitrary element, without knowing any other.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. Please see my edit in the opening post of this topic.

Comment: I added a minimal working example in my [Edit] in the opening post. For some reason the compiled version seems to be slower. Is there a way to speed it up? [Edit] It seems to be that slow because in the compiled version I cannot use a `PackedArray` for the `listExp`. Or is there a way to do it?

Comment: I may have a look at that tonight (in 5 hours or so...)

Comment: Slightly faster `vfun`: `With[{fac = 1. - dt*k/g, r = Range[0, nTot - 1]}, Transpose@{dt*r, Exp[Log[x0*fac] + Log[fac] r]}]`