# Is there any way that convert entire mathematica code to java or python?

Tags: functional-style, java, procedural-programming, python

I am novice to Mathematica.  I want to convert Mathematica code from my textbook to Java or Python to trace coding.

Comment: no. There is no way.  Try to do it by hand. But how will you convert `DSolve[]` to Java? Or how will you convert `Integrate` or `Simplify` and the thousands of commands in Mathematica to Java?  If the code contains no calls to Mathematica special build-in commands such as the above, but contains only basic commands, such as `Table`, `Print`, `If` etc..., then it can be possible to convert manually.

Comment: Nope... and it would be a waste of time anyway.  *Mathematica* is SOOO much more powerful than those languages that a single *Mathematica* function would need tens of thousands of lines in other languages.  And then there is curated data.  Etc.  Learn how to use *Mathematica* and its tracing functions.  MUCH better approach.

Comment: Maybe some day: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173256/5478

Comment: There's no built-in way (and for many things there isn't a standard correspondence), but instead of trying to make your Mathematica code look like python code (I did that when I first switched over and it's a terrible experience and gives you slow code) I would suggest that you look up [Functional Programming](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html) in a context you're more familiar with. Mathematica is primarily a functional programming language and using it as such will make you code cleaner, faster, and just generally make your life better.

Comment: There are [some libraries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4456/21734) which may help to port some small programs to other languages.

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "trace coding", but in general, the Mathematica evalution methods are very complicated, and could be documented better. Again, in general, in any computer language, I suggest breaking code into smaller pieces and placing frequent output statements to see what the results of evaluations are. There is a `Trace[]` command but it produces volumnious and confusing output. Most Mathematica commands are higher level than those in other languages that you mentioned. Depending on the particular Mathematica code, if it is simple enough, it may be possible to "transliterate" it into another langauges. In any case, you need to read the documentation for the Mathematica commands you will be using. The `FullForm[]` and `TreeForm[]` commands will help you to see what the Mathematics expressions you are using really look like.

Comment: There is also actually a debugger inside the notebook. I remember reading a  post here where one person actually managed to figure how to use i!   I never figured how to use the Mathematica debugger myself, but in theory it is supposed to be an actual working debugger.   For debugging I use Print statements and use a global flag to turn them off and on as needed.