# How to build a list of elements satisfying a certain property without building a list of all elements first?

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, filtering

Is there a way to *directly* build a list of elements that satisfy a certain property? More precisely, I am looking for a function `IncludeIf` (this is a placeholder name) that should work like `Table` but direcly drops all the unwanted elements. E.g.

```
IncludeIf[i, PrimePowerQ, {i, 1, 1000}]
```

should create a list of all prime powers among the numbers $\{1,...,1000\}$. The result should be the same as for

```
Select[Table[i, {i, 1, 1000}], PrimePowerQ]
```

but without the overhead of first creating a list of maybe *far to many* elements, and then dropping most of them.

A built-in-function would be preferred, but a work-around is welcome too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Do` together with `Reap`-`Sow`:

```
Reap[Do[If[EvenQ[i], Sow[i]], {i, 100}]][[2, 1]] // Short
(*{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, <<40>>, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100}*)
```

**EDIT**

It is interesting to compare the `Reap`-`Sow` approach with the linked lists approach.

`Reap`-`Sow` approach:

```
ClearAll[ReapSow];
SetAttributes[ReapSow, HoldAll];
ReapSow[expr_, cond_, spec_] := Reap[
  Do[If[cond, Sow[expr]], spec]
][[2, 1]];
```

Linked lists approach

```
ClearAll[LinkedLists];
SetAttributes[LinkedLists, HoldAll];
LinkedLists[expr_, cond_, spec_] := CompoundExpression[
 $temp = f[],
 Do[
   If[cond, $temp = f[$temp, expr]],
   spec
  ],
  List @@ Flatten[$temp]
];
```

here I intentionally do not introduce local variables not to fool `RepeatedTiming` by, e.g. `Module` overhead.

`` Internal`Bag `` cheat:

```
ClearAll[ReapSowCompiled];
SetAttributes[ReapSowCompiled, HoldAll];
ReapSowCompiled[expr_, cond_, spec_] := Compile[
  {},
  Module[
   {bag = Internal`Bag[{0}]},
   Do[If[cond, Internal`StuffBag[bag, expr]], spec];
   Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
];
cf = ReapSowCompiled[i, EvenQ[i], {i, 10^4}];
```

Tests in a fresh kernel:

```
(*A fresh kernel*)
mem1 = MemoryInUse[];
a = ReapSow[i, EvenQ[i], {i, 10^4}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
MemoryInUse[] - mem1
(*0.01*)
(*58992*)

(*A fresh kernel*)
mem1 = MemoryInUse[];
b = LinkedLists[i, EvenQ[i], {i, 10^4}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
MemoryInUse[] - mem1
(*0.01*)
(*410696*)

(*A fresh kernel*)
mem1 = MemoryInUse[];
c = cf[] // Rest; // AbsoluteTiming// First
MemoryInUse[] - mem1
(*0.000326986*)
(*47184*)
```

So, a complex tree structure of pointers seems to involve a bigger memory overhead then an optimized `Reap`-`Sow` or `Compiled` cheat.

Answer (score 11):

As compiled variant of `Sow` and `Reap`, you can use the undocumented [`` Internal`Bag ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845):

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{bag = Internal`Bag[{0}]},
    Do[If[EvenQ[i], Internal`StuffBag[bag, i]], {i, n}];
    Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
    ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

n = 10000000;
a = Reap[Do[If[EvenQ[i], Sow[i]], {i, n}]][[2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Rest[cf[n]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
```

> 5.39257
>
> 0.214701
>
> True

Comment: I wonder, is there a specific advantage of using these undocumented "bags" instead of normal lists and `AppendTo`? Is there a difference in the grwoth behavior of lists and bags? Does `Reap` and `Sow` use bags internally?

Comment: @M.Winter, `AppendTo` will lead to quadratic complexity instead of linear, I would not  recommend using `AppendTo` to build lists element-by-element.

Comment: @Anton Thank you. I expected something like this. Especially I expected that the lists memory grows only as large as absolutely necessary. Since I want to understand this really well, do you know something about the memory model of these "bags" or the implementation of `Reap`/`Sow` that makes them faster?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher cheater :) definitely +1. Maybe it is worth including a link to a SE question where `Internal``Bag` is explained in some more details, since it is undocumented functionality? Like this one https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/59438

Comment: @M.Winter, in general, the idea is very simple: `AppendTo` makes a completely new expression and copies all elements form the original expression plus the new element, while `Sow` just marks an expression to be collected (filling some stack, I suppose), which are collected by `Reap` only once, at the end. Regarding `Bag`s, I myself have discovered them only recently, I would recommend searching SE. SE can be called "The Documentation Centre for undocumented functions" :)

Comment: @M.Winter The main advantage of `Bag` is that it is compilable. Repeatedly appending to a list has quadratic complexity, but there are easy ways around this, e.g. using a linked list (which I can show you in another answer if you request it).  However, these solutions are not `Compile`able, while `Bag` is.

Comment: @M.Winter Just to be clear, the usual (and simplest) way is `Sow`/`Reap`, not a linked list. `Sow`/`Reap` are also not compilable though.