# Compile `DeleteCases`

Tags: compile

How is the function `DeleteCases` compilable if `Compile` does not support patterns?

My question refers to this thread [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-construct) where I want to use an `If[]` statement without the third argument required. Since my output of the `If[]` statement within compile always gives a positive real number, I'd like to get rid of the numbers which I invoke with a negative third argument in the `If[]` statement (the third arguments seems to be necessary so that the `If[]` statement is compiled at all).

Maybe there now might be even a better solution than this workaround provided by @Mr.Wizard but I do not really understand his suggestion (or is it meant to use `DeleteCases` outside of `Compile`?).

Comment: Only a restricted set of forms is supported in `Compile`. You can e.g. `DeleteCases[list, 123]`. I think only literal values can be used as the second argument.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out. I think that is what I encountered here. So it is not usable for my purpose, unfortunately. But I like Henrik's way of avoiding this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

In code for `Compile`, it might be a better idea not to delete bad cases but to collect only the good ones with [`` Internal`Bag ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1028).

If you have a certain but reasonably sized upper bound for the number od items to collect, you can also employ this less expensive way, using a packed array instead of a expandable data structure such as `` Internal`Bag ``:

First, preallocate an array `a` of sufficient size and a counter `c`, initialized by `0`. Then fill the array in a `Do` or `While` loop: Each time your `If` statement evaluates to `True`, increase the counter `c` and write the "good" item into `a[[c]]`. After having collected all items, truncate the array with `a[[1;;c]]`.

## Example

Here are two functions that search the first `n` positive integers for multiples of `3` or `5`:

`` Internal`Bag ``-based version (using the `Most[{0}]` hack to initiaize with an empty bag capable of collecting for integers):

```
cfBag = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Block[{bag},
    bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]];
    
    Do[
     If[Mod[i, 3] == 0 || Mod[i, 5] == 0,
      Internal`StuffBag[bag, i];
      ],
     {i, 1, n}];
    Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

And here is the array-based version:

```
cfArray = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Block[{a, c = 0},
    a = Table[0, {n}];
    c = 0;
    Do[
     If[Mod[i, 3] == 0 || Mod[i, 5] == 0,
      c++;
      a[[c]] = i;
      ],
     {i, 1, n}];
    If[c > 0, a[[1 ;; c]], {}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

Comparison:

```
r1 = cfBag[10000000]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = cfArray[10000000]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r1 == r2
```

> 0.288
>
> 0.313
>
> True

To my own surprise, `` Internal`Bag `` is faster. <s>Probably because the task is memory bound and because `a` is much larger than needed in the end (so, too much memory allocation and a potentially superfluous copy operation in the end).</s> The reason seems to be that a call like `a[[c]] = i;` always checks whether `c` is within the bounds of `a`. Deactivating that with `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` makes the two methods equally fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you maybe provide me with a minimal working example to see how that works out in practice? I only superficially read sth about `Internal`Bag` so far, but it sounded interesting to me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look at it as soon as I can :)

Comment: For some reason the example code with `Internal\`Bag` always seems to be slightly faster than the array based solution. Even with the specification of `RuntimeOptions->"Speed"`. At least on my machine. The difference is about 17% of time.

Comment: Do you now by chance how to use `AddTo` for the case of a list of counters where I want to count up different elements individually. The problem is that within `Compile` I cannot use `Part` because `AddTo` must refer to a symbol.

Comment: If you mean to `AddTo` one of the arrays submitted as arguments of a `CompiledFunction`: That is not possible. The input array is submitted to underlying the compiled library as static. If you mean to do such things, you have to use the LibraryLink interface and write the C-function by hand. But of course, you can `AddTo` any array that is constructed within the body of the `CompiledFunction` (e.g., `a[[c]] += 1` with the array `a` from the function `cfArray` above. Anyways, this sounds like a new question, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, sry I thought that minor question isn't worth a new question. I also figured out my mistake with the help of your comment. I sloppily used `Compiled\`GetElement` in the `a[[c]] += 1` step, instead of using `Part`. I guess there is no equivalent to `Compiled\`GetElement` for writing operations. As the name suggests `Compiled\`GetElement` can of course only be used for read operations.

Comment: You're right. I also haven't found any ``Compile`GetElement`` equivalent for writing, yet.

Comment: Just need to be careful when you use the `With` construct and replace everything with `part=Compile\`GetElement` as you once suggested to me and then not remember the difference between `part` and `Part` :D