# Find and number sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

I implemented the following routine.

```
array1 = {12, -12, 14, 12, 1, -3, 1, 1, 2, 7, 8, 102, 2, 3, 3, 1, 332,
11, 23, 2, -2, 13, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -121, 131};
```

I want to find sublists which consist of consecutive numbers which absolute values are smaller than a certain treshold (Lim=5). I also want to have a parameter for the length of the sublists (Len=3).

```
Module[{Ar, Pos, Lim, Len},
 Ar = #;
 Lim = 5;
 Len = 3;
 Position[Ar, x_ /; Abs[x] < Lim] // Flatten[#] & // Set[Pos, #] &;
 Select[Split[Pos, #2 - #1 == 1 &], Length[#] > Len &]
 ] &[array1] // Set[PosInt, #] &;
```

Now I have the positions of the sublists.

```
PosInt // Print;
{{5,6,7,8,9},{13,14,15,16},{24,25,26,27,28,29}}
```

The next thing I would like to have is an array which includes the number and the position of the sublists. I have the following solution.

```
array2 = ConstantArray[0, Length@array1];
Module[{IntNum, Num, Pos},
Pos = #;
MapIndexed[(
   IntNum = First@#2;
   Num = #1;
   Map[(array2[[#]] = IntNum
      ) &, Num];
   ) &, Pos]
] &[PosInt];
```

The desired result is saved as array2.

```
array2 // Print;
{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0}
```

My implementation yields the right result. Nevertheless I'm sure it is possible to find a more elegant solution. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you aware that in Mathematica `expression` standing by itself on a line at top-level is essentially the same as `expression // Print;`?

Comment: @m_goldberg Thx for your comment. You are right, that's superfluous.

Comment: But the first position smaller than `5` is for `-12` which is `2` right then why it starts with `5` in the position list `{5,6,7,8,9}`

Comment: @Hubble07 Thank you! The absolute Number `Abs[]` has to be smaller. I did edit the question.

Comment: One more doubt. What about position `20` and `21`. I mean what if the after taking absolute value we get two same numbers.

Comment: @Hubble07 Right, but I also do have the criteria that the sequence has to have a Length longer than 3 (`Len=3; Length[#]>Len`).

Answer (score 4):

Currently, I address only your first problem. This is not really *Mathematica*-like but about 250 times faster than your approach.

Here is the `CompiledFunction` that I use; It goes linearly through the list and collects starting and ending index of each run in a [`` Internal`Bag ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845).

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {Lim, _Integer}, {Len, _Integer}},
   Block[{c, bag, x, α},
    α = 0;
    c = 0;
    bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]];
    Do[
     x = Compile`GetElement[a, i];
     If[Abs[x] < Lim,
      If[c == 0, α = i;];
      c++;
      ,
      If[c > Len,
       Internal`StuffBag[bag, α];
       Internal`StuffBag[bag, i - 1];
       ];
      c = 0;
      ],
     {i, 1, Length[a]}];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[bag, All], 2]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Here is your method in a (IMHO) more legible form:

```
f = {a, Lim, Len} \[Function] Select[
    Split[Flatten[Position[a, x_ /; Abs[x] < Lim]], #2 - #1 == 1 &],
    Length[#] > Len &
    ];
```

Let's create a large array of pseudorandom integers and run the two functions on it:

```
a = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {1000000}];

PosInt = f[a, Lim, Len]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
PosInt2 = cf[a, Lim, Len]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

The output of `cf` is slightly different from that of `f`; it returns only the first and last position index of each desired sublist. So we can compare the results in either of the two follwoing ways:

```
PosInt[[All, {1, -1}]] == PosInt2
PosInt == Range @@@ PosInt2
```

> True
>
> True

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Until now I didn't use `CompiledFunction` at all. Maybe I should start using, your impelementation of `AppendTo` is very useful as well.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a good exercise to employ some of the newer functions.

```
list =
  {12, -12, 14, 12, 1, -3, 1, 1, 2, 7, 8, 102, 2, 3, 3, 1, 332, 11, 
   23, 2, -2, 13, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -121, 131};

lim = 5;
len = 3;
```

The 2 following sequence-functions give a rather short solution of the problem, but get very slow with long lists. As a rule of thumb: I don't use them for lists with more than 1000 elements.

Using `SequenceSplit` to get runs of integers smaller than `lim`:

```
split = SequenceSplit[list, {a_} /; Abs[a] > lim]
```

{{1, -3, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 1}, {2, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

Using `SequencePosition` to get first and last positions of the runs:

```
pos = 
  Cases[{a_, b_} /; b - a >= len - 1] @ 
    Map[Splice @ SequencePosition[list, #] &, split]
```

{{5, 9}, {13, 16}, {24, 29}}

Span and index the positions:

```
span = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &] @ MapApply[Span] @ pos
```

{{1, 5 ;; 9}, {2, 13 ;; 16}, {3, 24 ;; 29}}

Using `Fold` and `ReplaceAt` to get the desired result:

```
Fold[
 ReplaceAt[_ :> #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] @ #1 &,
 Table[0, Length @ list],
 span]
```

{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0}

Comment: It is a superlative application and a tutorial for these functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
array1 = {12, -12, 14, 12, 1, -3, 1, 1, 2, 7, 8, 102, 2, 3, 3, 1, 332,
    11, 23, 2, -2, 13, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -121, 131};

lim = 5;
len = 3;

t = (Abs@#) < lim & /@ array1 // Boole // 
  SequenceReplace[#, 
    k : {0, Repeated[1, {1, len}], 0} :> 
     Sequence @@ Table[0, Length@k]] &;

(Split[t] // Map[First] // Accumulate) Split[t] // Flatten
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0}

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = {12, -12, 14, 12, 1, -3, 1, 1, 2, 7, 8, 102, 2, 3, 3, 1,
      332, 11, 23, 2, -2, 13, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -121, 131};

t = 5;

le = 3;
```

Using `SplitBy` and `Select`:

```
l2 = Thread[Range@Length@# -> #] &@l1;

conds = Length@# > le - 1 && And @@ Thread[#[[{1, -1}, 2]] < t] &;

sp = Select[SplitBy[l2, Abs[#[[2]]] < t &], conds];
```

We obtain the first and last positions of the sublists as follows:

```
pos = #[[{1, -1}, 1]] & /@ sp

(*{{5, 9}, {13, 16}, {24, 29}}*)
```

Using `Range` and index the positions:

```
rule = Splice@Thread[#1 -> ConstantArray[#2[[1]], Length@#1]] &;

rep = MapIndexed[rule]@MapApply[Range]@pos;
```

Finally, using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[Table[0, Length@l1], rep]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0}