# Why is ParallelDo slower than Do?

Tags: parallelization

I have problems to write parallel code in mathematica.
Why is

```
candidates = {};
SetSharedVariable[candidates];

Do[
  ParallelDo[

   eq = RandomReal[] + RandomReal[];
    AppendTo[candidates, eq]

   , {j, 1, 1000}]
  , {i, 1, 10}]
```

slower than the non parallel version

```
candidates = {};
Do[
  Do[

   eq = RandomReal[] + RandomReal[];
    AppendTo[candidates, eq]

   , {j, 1, 1000}]
  , {i, 1, 10}]
```

?

Comment: I reverted your post to before the edit because it looks like a different question (like Henrik said in his comment). Note, however, that if you ask it in precisely such form it will be likely closed due to not enough info: you need to provide the minimal working example, not through some undefined functions into a piece of code that no one will be able to run and test.

Comment: See here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48296/12 I suggest you don't use SetSharedVariable until you get quite fluent in using the parallel tools.  It effectively "unparallelizes" your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because managing write access to shared memory is expensive: Subprocesses have to wait until they are granted write access (because another process uses that ressource).

Moreover, it is in general more efficient to use `Parallel` only upon the most outer loop construct.

By the way: Using `Append` and `AppendTo` are the worst methods to build a list, because they involve a copy of the full list each time another element is appended. Instead of complexity $O(n)$ for a list of $n$ elements, you get an implementation of complexity $O(n^2)$. Better use `Table` or, if you don't know how long the list is about to get, use `Sow` and `Reap`. [`` Internal`Bag ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845) is a further option, and it is even compilable.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped a lot.
I just dont understand how to use Sow and Reap to avoid Append

To be more specific: instead of ParallelDo I use now ParallelTable:

eq = ParallelTable[
   FNumeric[
    SetPrecision[N[monlistnumeric[[i]] + monlistnumeric[[j]], 20], 10]]
   , {j, jj}];

FNumeric is a function, that returns either 0 or a value I want to store. I then do

eq = DeleteCases[eq, 0];
candidates = Join[candidates, eq];

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @MatthiasHeller, you're welcome. How is this new code related to your post? You should consider a new post with your real problem and all relevant data. I may have a look. In general, depending on the details, there are various ways to perform the computation efficiently; these way might not use `Parallel` at all, but rather `Compile`d code.