# Avoiding the memory requirements of an accumulation of returned Nulls (etc)

Tags: memory, hold, sequence

There is an extensive but relatively old answer to a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-construct), and there are many Qs and As about avoiding using Table where possible.

My problem is a mixture of the two: I have been attempting to reproduce some long-standing results about Carmichael Numbers, and the algorithms work, but for the (vast majority) of numbers the call to the evaluation function returns Null, Nothing, ##&[] or whatever, and *all of them* use memory if the evaluation function is called from Table. So I have three related questions:

(a) avoiding the usual looping constructs (because the number of iterators is a variable, which is relatively easy to implement from within Table, but not to my knowledge from For, While, Do, etc), how can one call a function perhaps 500,000,000 times and avoid the accumulation of Null returns that everyone seems to think "unavoidable" because MMA always returns "something";

(b) is there a way to delete returns "on reception" from within Table - a bit like "sort on entry" except "delete on reception" - so that they never appear in the output list from Table;

(c) is there a new update/insight that means that a function call can return *literally* "nothing" rather than "something pretending to be nothing" (like Null or even Nothing except to a List).

I have no problem deleting the Nulls (etc) retrospectively, but I do have a problem with the memory requirements and consequent speed issues that result from generating/storing them.

I am wondering whether the answer is to abandon the function-call approach and just do everything within one Table so that Nothing gets its just desserts from within a Table-generated List, but the aesthetics don't appeal much.

Comment: Use [`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html). It will apply the function to all the items but throw away the return values. E.g `Scan[f[#]&, {1,2,3,4}]`. Otherwise, if you need _some_ return values, use `Reap` and `Sow`. e.g `Reap[Do[ x = foo[]; If[x=!=Null, Sow[x]]; , 1000]][[2,1]]`

Comment: Have a look at my [lazyList](https://github.com/ssmit1986/lazyLists) package. It's specifically made for dealing with large lists without having to hold everything in memory at once.

Comment: I agree with Flinty here that you don't seem to be using the wrong data structure for your type of data. If you don't want to keep one output per function call, then you shouldn't be using `Table`. You should be using `Sow`/`Reap` as Flinty suggests, or [another datastructure](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataStructures.html).

Comment: ...Although, whatever you do, don't append to a list (it will be unnecessarily slow). `DynamicArray` seems to fit the bill. I think it might be a modern version of a much older and well-known but undocumented data structure called [bags](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile), which is suitable for this situation. Incidentally, bags is how `Sow` is implemented internally.

Comment: Very helpful comments. Scan: I don't think it is suitable; Sow/Reap certainly; I have installed the lazyList package and am in the process of learning its capabilities; "alternative data structures" I will certainly explore.

Comment: ```Update:``` Reap[Do[...Sow...]] with variable numbers of interdependent iterators works a treat as ```flinty``` suggested. Just grunted through 696,190,560 tests with no memory issues (although it isn't exactly quick, so that's the next challenge: took 13,767 seconds using ```//Timing``` on a newly-installed Wolfram Engine 12.1 from Terminal, but without compilation, although that's still more than 50,000 tests per second). I don't think Reap/Sow compiles (does it?), so will try DataStructures as ```C.E.``` suggests using 12.1 and then try to get my head around ```lazyLists```.